Table Missing Values
I'm trying to improve my ability to read math and physics equations, so I borrowed this code from someone on GitHub. I'm a bit of a latex novice. I was having issues getting the document to build at all but got those resolved. Now the table is blank when the PDF builds. How do I get the characters to display?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\CmdTbl}[2]{
  \textsc {#2}
  & $  \csname #1 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname var #1 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname up #1 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname upvar #1 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname #2 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname var #2 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \mathsf { \csname #2 \endcsname } $ 
  & $  \mathtt { \csname #2 \endcsname } $ 
  & $  \csname Up #1 \endcsname  $ 
  & $  \csname Upvar #1 \endcsname  $
  \\
}
\newcommand { \columntitle }[1]{ \textsf {#1}}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
   \begin{tabular}{|c||cc|cc|cccc|cc|} \hline 
    \textsc {Greek letters}
    & \multicolumn {2}{c|}{ \columntitle {Lowercase}}
    & \multicolumn {2}{c|}{ \columntitle {Upright lowercase}}
    & \multicolumn {4}{c|}{ \columntitle {Uppercase}}
    & \multicolumn {2}{c|}{ \columntitle {Upright uppercase}}
    \\
    \cline {2-11}
    
    & \columntitle {normal}
    & \columntitle {variant}
    & \columntitle {normal}
    & \columntitle {variant}
    & \columntitle {normal}
    & \columntitle {variant}
    & \columntitle {Sans-serif}
    & \columntitle {Monospaced}
    & \columntitle {normal}
    & \columntitle {variant}
    \\
    \hline 
     \CmdTbl {alpha}{Alpha}
     \CmdTbl {beta}{Beta}
     \CmdTbl {gamma}{Gamma}
     \CmdTbl {delta}{Delta}
     \CmdTbl {epsilon}{Epsilon}
     \CmdTbl {zeta}{Zeta}
     \CmdTbl {eta}{Eta}
     \CmdTbl {theta}{Theta}
     \CmdTbl {iota}{Iota}
     \CmdTbl {kappa}{Kappa}
     \CmdTbl {lambda}{Lambda}
     \CmdTbl {mu}{Mu}
     \CmdTbl {no}{No}
     \CmdTbl {xi}{Xi}
     \CmdTbl {omicron}{Omicron}
     \CmdTbl {pi}{Pi}
     \CmdTbl {rho}{Rho}
     \CmdTbl {sigma}{Sigma}
     \CmdTbl {tau}{Tau}
     \CmdTbl {upsilon}{Upsilon}
     \CmdTbl {phi}{Phi}
     \CmdTbl {chi}{Chi}
     \CmdTbl {psi}{Psi}
     \CmdTbl {omega}{Omega}
   \hline 
  \end{tabular}
 \end{landscape}
 \end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE! You not enter any values into table cells below the first two row (except to the first column). What should be in those cells?  Please provide an sketch of first few table rows.

@Zarko I was thinking that the \CmdTbl command was expanding to fill the table

The opposite problem is discussed at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands.  Basically, you were trying to use the commands \alpha , \alpha var , etc (note the extra spaces).

You have a lot of spaces in your \CmdTbl definition. Use
\newcommand\CmdTbl[2]{%
    \textsc{#2}
    &   $\csname#1\endcsname $   & $  \csname var#1\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \csname up#1\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \csname upvar#1\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \csname#2\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \csname var#2\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \mathsf {\csname#2\endcsname} $ 
    & $  \mathtt {\csname#2\endcsname} $ 
    & $  \csname Up#1\endcsname  $ 
    & $  \csname Upvar#1\endcsname  $
    \\
}



This was it. Thanks!

Any idea why the Uppercase variant column is empty?

Depends to the font. You have tp choose one with uppercase greek letters.

I think you need to remove one more space in \csname up#1 \endcsname to get upright lowercase normal.

@Teepeemm:  true ... I corrected it in the code
