# writing simple fractions (1/2, 1/4) in social science text

Tags: fractions

As part of a social science text, in one place I need to write fractions like 1/2, 1/4, 1/3. How can I write these fractions in an elegant way without using mathematical packages?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [nicefrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac)? But I guess [xfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) may be better now.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than the standard LaTeX in-text math `$ $` environment?

Comment: Could this question be of help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5-%c2%bd?rq=1

Comment: Seems to me the answers to this question are likely to be more what the OP is after:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28866/how-to-print-frac12-by-a-single-unicode-character