# Extract first & last characters of macro argument?

Tags: calculations, strings, parameters

In LaTeX, how do I extract/isolate/determine the first and last characters of a macro argument?

Specifically, in the case I'm dealing with, the argument happens to be a base-10 integer (call it N).  One way I can think of for the rightmost digit is to compute N mod 10, and for the leftmost digit to repeatedly divide by 10—except I haven't attempted anything like that yet and I don't know how reasonable that is or even if that is possible in (La)TeX.  Extracting the characters as string entities would be fine too; I have no requirement of producing numeric values.  (Edit: I forgot to mention earlier that I would prefer the solution to work for arbitrarily large numeric values—or at least up to, say, 7 or 10 digits—which might necessitate a string-base solution rather than a numeric solution.)

Ultimately, I just need the isolated characters in a form that I can compare using if/then constructs, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  (something to extract rightmost digit of #1)
  (something to extract leftmost digit of #2)
  ...
  \ifthenelse{\rightmost\equal 2}{\kern.02em}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\rightmost\equal 4}{\kern.03em}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\rightmost\equal 7}{\kern-.02em}{}%
  ...
  \ifthenelse{\leftmost\equal 1}{\kern.02em}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\leftmost\equal 4}{\kern-.03em}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\leftmost\equal 5}{\kern.03em}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\leftmost\equal 7}{\kern.03em}{}%
  ...
}
```

*Additional background:* This is for fine-tuning the kerning in the numerator and denominator of fractions (related question [Improving kerning in fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/improved-kerning-in-fractions)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the [`xstring`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring?lang=en) package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastletter]%
    First letter: \firstletter

    Last letter: \lastletter
}

\begin{document}
    \mymacro{ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

I’m a little busy so please excuse that I didn’t build it in you MWE ;-)

Comment: You should mention how to store the result in a variable. I know it is an optional argument somewhere, but I never remember where to place it. For the OP, that's going to be necessary to perform the tests afterwards.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Included it while you where writing, but thanks :-)

Comment: @Tobi: I discovered that the hard way, before you wrote this. Boy, was I surprised when `\let\leftmost\StrLeft{#1}{1}` didn't do what I expected! :)

Comment: @ToddLehman: I’m not sure but I guess the problem with the `\let` is that it stores `\StrLeft` to `\leftmost` an ignores `{#1}{1}` so after that you could say `\leftmost{#1}{1}` but that doesn’t help ;-) After processing the `\let` operation the `{#1}{1}` is interpreted as more or less normal text and printed out

Comment: @Tobi: ooh—even better than `\StrLeft` and `\StrRight` are `\IfBeginWith` and `\IfEndWith`—also part of `string`—they don't require storing the value in a temporary variable. :)

Comment: @ToddLehman. Yes. I didn’t read your question very considerately O:-)

Answer (score 17):

Or in classic TeX; the following defines `\fst` and `\lst` to be the first and last characters (or be empty for short input)

```
\def\fl#1{\flx#1\empty\empty\empty}
\def\flx#1#2#3\empty{%
\edef\fst{#1}%
 \edef\cdar{#2}%
 \edef\cddr{#3}%
  \ifx\cddr\empty
    \let\lst\cdar
  \else
     \expandafter\flxx
   \fi
  #3}
\def\flxx#1#2\empty{%
 \edef\car{#1}%
  \ifx\car\empty
  \else
     \let\lst\car
     \expandafter\flxx
   \fi
  #2\empty}

\immediate\write20{===}
\fl{}\immediate\write20{[\fst][\lst]}
\immediate\write20{===1}
\fl{1}\immediate\write20{[\fst][\lst]}
\immediate\write20{===12}
\fl{12}\immediate\write20{[\fst][\lst]}
\immediate\write20{===123}
\fl{123}\immediate\write20{[\fst][\lst]}
\immediate\write20{===1234}
\fl{1234}\immediate\write20{[\fst][\lst]}

\end



===
[][]
===1
[1][]
===12
[1][2]
===123
[1][3]
===1234
[1][4]
```

Comment: It is so cool that there are so many ways to do this!

Comment: :-) It should be (car and (cdr  which are, in lisp the head and tail respectively of a list, the names being IBM 704 assembler instructions, originally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR

Comment: as for local groups yes could be grouped, or you could avoid defining macros at all and just pass them to a following command as #1 and #2, it depends how the OP wants to use it...

Comment: David: My comment, to which you have responded, was inadvertently deleted. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 13):

Here are 3 solutions using `expl3`, depending on your requirements. To perform the tests, I'd use `\prg_case_int:nnn` rather than an ad-hoc bunch of `\ifthenelse` statements: those are slower.

(1) The simplest is to use `\tl_head:n{#1}` to access the first digit of the number, and `\int_mod:nn {#1}{10}` for the last one. This works for numbers less than 2^{31}, and with versions of expl3 from roughly June 2011 onwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand {\foo} [2] {
  \prg_case_int:nnn { \int_mod:nn {#1} {10} }
    {
      {1} { \kern .02em \relax }
      {4} { \kern .03em \relax }
      {7} { \kern -.02em \relax }
    }
    { }
  \prg_case_int:nnn { \tl_head:n {#2} }
    {
      {1} { \kern .02em \relax }
      {4} { \kern -.03em \relax }
      {5} { \kern .03em \relax }
      {7} { \kern .03em \relax }
    }
    { }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(2) With a recent version of `expl3` (mid-january 2012 onwards), using `\tl_item:nn` is probably best, as it will work for any integer, and you probably don't really want to enforce that your numerator and denominator are integers anyways. Namnely, `\tl_item:nn {#1} {<integer>}` gives the `<integer>`-th token in the token list, starting at zero for the left-most token (first digit), with negative indices starting at -1 for the right-most token. In particular,

```
\tl_item:nn { abcd } { 0 } % => a, left-most token
\tl_item:nn { abcd } { 2 } % => c
\tl_item:nn { abcd } { -1 } % => d, right-most token
\tl_item:nn { abcd } { -5 } % => nothing: index out of bounds.
```

(3) If you need a solution which works both for arbitrarily long integers and for older versions of `expl3`, then you can replace the lines from `\newcommand` to `\prg_case_int:nnn { \int_mod:nn {#1} {10} }` by

```
%----->8---- cut here
\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl
\newcommand {\foo} [2] {
  \tl_clear:N \l_foo_tl
  \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { \tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl {##1} }
  \prg_case_int:nnn { \l_foo_tl }
%-----8<---- cut here
```

The idea is that I go through the string and store each character in `\l_foo_tl`, until reaching the end of the string. Hence, the last character remains in `\l_foo_tl`. That's a good replacement for `\int_mod:nn {#1} {10}` to get the last digit. However, the two other solutions I gave above are better long-term (especially the `\tl_item:nn` one).

Comment: I chose the easier method; I would probably write two different commands, so the OP can call them with suitable arguments in the main fraction building command.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: It looks like this will work for me! (Just did a quick test.) I'm using the MacTeX/TeXLive 2011 distribution. I see that `expl3` is intended for LaTeX3. Is it a transitional package that will be obsolete when LaTeX3 is released? Can I consider it to be stable? (Wasn't quite clear to me from the docs.) Also, I would like to understand why the `\relax` is necessary in the above. Where might I read about that? I've been using LaTeX2e for a while but this is the first LaTeX3 code I've encountered.

Comment: @Todd: yes, `expl3` is stable, and should remain almost entirely unchanged (except that `\usepackage{expl3}` won't be needed anymore) in LaTeX3. At the moment, LaTeX3 is `expl3` (and some additional packages). We still need quite some time (two to five years, I'd say, but that can't possibly be official) before being able to produce a full format. The `\kern ...\relax` construction has nothing to do with LaTeX3. It is a subtlety of TeX itself: try `\newcommand{\putkern}[1]{\kern#1\relax}` then `abc\pukern{0pt} def`. If you omit the `\relax`, the space after `\putkern{0pt}` disappears.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand your comment: what did you "choose"?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the docs that explain the peculiar `:nn` and `:nnn` syntax.  Does the number of `n`s govern the maximum length of the integer/string in base 10?  I forgot to mention that I need this to work with arbitrarily large integers (well, at least up to 10 digits or so).

Comment: @ToddLehman No. The `:nn` syntax tells you how many arguments the function expects. `\tl_head:n` expects one argument: the token list (or integer in your case) from which to extract the first token. `\int_mod:nn` expects two arguments: the number and the modulus. Integers in TeX are limited to 32 bits, signed, so roughly 2 billions. In your case, the `\tl_item:nn {<your integer>} {-1}` solution may be better since it works with tokens (digits) and won't care about the length of the integer. But it is only available in very recent versions of `expl3`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was just about to answer the question with the same approach as your final version. :)