# White space unexpectedly lost when trimming a string

Tags: latex3, expl3

I'm trying to follow the example given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43348/22413)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_seq
\tl_new:N  \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_trash_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn  \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_seq {} {#1}
      \seq_pop_left:NN   \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_seq \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_trash_tl
      \seq_pop_right:NN  \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_seq \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_trash_tl
      \use:x  { \seq_map_function:NN \l_ae_insertQuotedMatter_seq \exp_not:n }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\removeQuotes{"Hello World"}

\end{document}
```

But this does more than I want. The white space is lost.

Two provisos:  (1)
I would prefer not to have to write `\removeQuotes{"Hello\ World"}`.  Also, (2) I would prefer not to have to load an entire new package (such as `xstring`) just to accomplish this one task.

**UPDATE**

I've also tried something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    {
      \tl_reverse:n { \tl_tail:n { \tl_reverse:n { \tl_tail:n { #1 } } } }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\removeQuotes{"Hello World"}

\removeQuotes{"Hello\ World"}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error:

```
! Argument of \tl_tail:n has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12     \removeQuotes{"Hello World"}

?
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Will come up with a solution in a bit, but to be going on with note what the docs say: `Spaces on both sides of each \meta{item} are ignored`. For an `item` that is just a space, that means it disappears.

Comment: Why do you work with a seq instead of tl?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I was following the linked example because it was straightforward and easy to understand.

Comment: how about the `expl3` version of `\def\removequotes#1{\@removequotes#1}\def\@removequotes"#1"{#1}`?

Comment: @cgnieder: I did it ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second approach can be solved by generating a variant of the used commands:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_reverse:n { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_tail:n { f }
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    {
      \tl_reverse:f { \tl_tail:f { \tl_reverse:f { \tl_tail:f { #1 } } } }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

There are also another approach:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    {
     \tl_set:Nn \tl_tmpa_tl { #1 } 
     \tl_remove_all:Nn \tl_tmpa_tl { " }
     \tl_use:N \tl_tmpa_tl
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Heres the approach suggest by cgnieder:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    {
     \__ellett_remove_quotes_aux:n { #1 }
    }
\cs_set:Npn \__ellett_remove_quotes_aux:n #1
 {
   \__ellett_remove_quotes_aux_i:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__ellett_remove_quotes_aux_i:w  "#1" \q_stop
 {
  #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: `aux` functions, _etc._, should be internal (`\__...`) :-)

Comment: I like the second approach.   But I'm wondering why in the third approach you need the middle `\ellett_remove_quotes_aux:n` function.  Why the *middle man*?

Comment: @A.Ellett: The same reason as Joseph.

Answer (score 6):

The reason that the `seq` function behaves as-observed is that it is designed to strip out spaces 'around' items, and for an item which consists only of spaces that means removing it entirely. Thus an alternative approach is required.

While the token list functions can do this, I would probably use a more traditional TeX approach based around delimited arguments. The question doesn't specify behaviour if the first and last tokens are not quotes or if quotes are nested within the text. Thus the following may not be 'desired' in all cases, but is a start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
    { \ae_remove_quotes:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \ae_remove_quotes:n #1
  { \__ae_remove_quotes:w #1 " " \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__ae_remove_quotes:w #1 " #2 " #3 \q_stop
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      {#2}
      {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\removeQuotes{"Hello World"}

\removeQuotes{"Hello\ World"}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused about how you defined the third function.  Yours is so much more elaborate than @MarcoDaniel 's.  What's going here?

Comment: Similar to what I asked @MarcoDaniel.  Why the *middle function*?  Why not just define `\removeQuotes` through a direct call to `\__ae_remove_quotes:w`?

Comment: @A.Ellett The LaTeX3 approach is that document commands such as `\removeQuotes` should call 'well-behaved' code level commands. Something like `\__ae_remove_quotes:w` is not 'well-behaved' as it needs a particular set of tokens in its input (at least two `"` and a trailing `\q_stop`), so I've wrapped it up inside a function which does include that.

Comment: I see what's going on with your third function now.  Also, thank you for the explanation about the LaTeX3 approach: it explains something that I've seen in other's code and where I haven't understood the call to an *apparently superfluous* function.

Answer (score 5):

The mandatory solution with `l3regex`. Unquoted material passes through unchanged.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeQuotes}{m}
 {
  \ae_remove_quotes:n { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__ae_string_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ae_remove_quotes:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__ae_string_temp_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A \" (.*) \" \Z } { \1 } \l__ae_string_temp_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__ae_string_temp_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\removeQuotes{"Hello World"}

\removeQuotes{"Hello\ World"}

\removeQuotes{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I must learn l3regex ;-)

Comment: I'd been thinking of trying a `l3regex` solution.