# pgfplots: get color setting from table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to plot multiple lines using pgfplots.

Each of the lines should have a color, depending on the group it belongs to.

In the example attached, a table is provided, containing all the coordinates for the lines and additional information which should be used to decide which color to use

I tried a few things, but obviously I'm too unexperienced with LATEX/pgfplots.

It would be cool if someone could give me a hint,

Thanks, Tobi

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}  

\pgfplotstableread{  
% This table holds the coordinates for multiple lines sharing the same x-values.
% The x-values are provided in the first column, the y-values in the subsequent columns.
% The character in the first row indicates the group the line belongs to
t   a   a   a   b   b   c   c   c   c  
-1  0   -2  -1  1   0   2   2   1   1  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   3   2   4   9   8   6   7   9   5  
2   4.5 3   6   13  12  9   10  12  8  
3   5.8 3.5 7   15  14  11  12  13  9  
4   5.1 3.3 6.5 14  13  10  11  12  8.5  
5   5   3.1 6.4 14  13  10  11  12  8.4  
}\atable  

% These are the colors I want to use for the 3 groups (a,b,c)  
\definecolor{mycolorA}{named}{red}  
\definecolor{mycolorB}{named}{green}  
\definecolor{mycolorC}{named}{blue}  

% Ok, let's plot the data  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}[no markers]  

        % Loop over columns present (If someone knows a shorter way to do this please let me know)  
        \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\atable}  
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} 
        {% The loop starts here       

            % Here somehow the character in the first row  has to be read out.  
            % if the character in the first row of the current column \i 
            % is equal to 'a' then use mycolorA, if 'b' use mycolorB etc  
            \addplot table[x index=0,y index=\i] {\atable};  

        }  

    \end{axis};  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do things per column via `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn` loop where you get the column name and the index as macros and you avoid some of the code. I've used `xstring` package as Jake mentioned but I still think that this is not a good structure for keeping track of styles. I would recommend using custom cycle lists.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}  

\pgfplotstableread{  
t   a   a   a   b   b   c   c   c   c  
-1  0   -2  -1  1   0   2   2   1   1  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   3   2   4   9   8   6   7   9   5  
2   4.5 3   6   13  12  9   10  12  8  
3   5.8 3.5 7   15  14  11  12  13  9  
4   5.1 3.3 6.5 14  13  10  11  12  8.5  
5   5   3.1 6.4 14  13  10  11  12  8.4  
}\atable  


\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}[no markers,a/.style={red},b/.style={green},c/.style={blue}]  

\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\atable\as\colname{%
\StrLeft{\colname}{1}[\mycolname]
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=0\else%
\expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\mycolname] table[x=t,y index=\pgfplotstablecol] {\atable};
\fi
}
    \end{axis};  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, much more elegant!

Comment: @Jake Thanks but I think your answer is more general, and I think it should stay though for the expansion demonstration. Would you mind undeleting it?

Comment: Awesome, thank you both for your quick answers. both works fine for me, yet I don't fully understand why :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve a particular column name using `\pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex`. In this case, because the column names are not unique, this macro won't just return `a`, `b`, and `c`, but `a-index1`, `a-index2`, etc. To extract only the first character from a macro, you can use the `xstring` package (see [Extract first & last characters of macro argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43200/extract-first-last-characters-of-macro-argument)). To call styles using macros, you can use Andrew Stacey's approach from [How to submit a set of tikz command with pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85637/how-to-submit-a-set-of-tikz-command-with-pgfkeys). Note that you'll have to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of `\foreach` to make sure that the macros are executed at the proper time:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xstring}    
\begin{document}  

\pgfplotstableread{  
% This table holds the coordinates for multiple lines sharing the same x-values.
% The x-values are provided in the first column, the y-values in the subsequent columns.
% The character in the first row indicates the group the line belongs to
t   a   a   a   b   b   c   c   c   c  
-1  0   -2  -1  1   0   2   2   1   1  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   3   2   4   9   8   6   7   9   5  
2   4.5 3   6   13  12  9   10  12  8  
3   5.8 3.5 7   15  14  11  12  13  9  
4   5.1 3.3 6.5 14  13  10  11  12  8.5  
5   5   3.1 6.4 14  13  10  11  12  8.4  
}\atable  

% These are the colors I want to use for the 3 groups (a,b,c)  
\definecolor{mycolorA}{named}{red}  
\definecolor{mycolorB}{named}{green}  
\definecolor{mycolorC}{named}{blue} 

\tikzset{
    a/.style={
        mycolorA
    },
    b/.style={
        mycolorB
    },
    c/.style={
        mycolorC
    },
    execute style/.style = {#1},
    execute macro/.style = {execute style/.expand once=#1},
    extract group/.code={
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex#1\of\atable\to\group         
        \StrLeft{\group}{1}[\firstletter]
    }
}

% Ok, let's plot the data  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}[no markers]  

        % Loop over columns present (If someone knows a shorter way to do this please let me know)  
        \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\atable}  
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\pgfmathresult} 
        {% The loop starts here        
            \addplot [extract group=#1, execute macro=\firstletter] table [x index=0,y index=#1] {\atable};  

        }  

    \end{axis};  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Percusse's answer is better