# Elsarticle: obtaining appendix section label letter?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, elsarticle, xstring

When using Elsevier's article template `elsarticle`, the references to appendix sections return `Appendix  X` instead of `X`. I personally dislike the double space, so I was trying to create a macro to retrieve the `X` from the reference. I tried to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43202/293149) guidance to create such a macro using `xstring`'s `\StrRight`, which allows the retrieval of the last character of a given string. However, I cannot understand the result I am obtaining. Below, I present a minimal code to reproduce the problem and also a screenshot of its result.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\getLastLetter}[1]{%
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastLetter]%
    \lastLetter
}

\begin{document}

The label letter of \ref{appendixSectionLabel} is \getLastLetter{\ref{appendixSectionLabel}}.
 
\appendix
\section{}
\label{appendixSectionLabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `elsarticle.cls` defines `\appendixname` with `\def\appendixname{Appendix }` (with the space). I can't be sure, but this sounds like a typo to me. You can try `\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}` and observe for side effects...

Comment: @gusbrs Your workaround was good enough to solve my root problem. Thank you.