# Prevent LuaLaTeX from splitting umlauts

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Cambria}
\begin{document}aöz\end{document}
```

Compiling this into a PDF using `lualatex` and extracting the text using `pdftotext`, I get the string `aö z`, that is:

```
U+0061(a) U+006f(o) U+0308(combining diaeresis) U+0020(space) U+007a(z)
```

Two problems with this: there's an unnecessary space (due to some PDF formatting trickery, the uncompressed datastream shows `Tm[<…>125<01C5>-124<…>]TJ`), and I don't want the umlaut to be split into base and combining character because for some reason that renders weirdly when changing the font size. I want the output to be

```
U+0061(a) U+00f6(ö) U+007a(z)
```

And the worst thing: with `\setmainfont{Lucida Grande}`, I get exactly that. Just not with Cambria.

Both are in TTF format. Checking the fonts in `fontforge` shows that both their `U+00f6` glyphs are defined as composed of `U+006f U+0308`, only difference being that Cambria defines its OTF Class as “Base Glyph” while in Lucida Grande it's “Automatic” (no idea what that means).

---

It is a `fontspec` specific problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\font\foo={name:Cambria} at 10pt
\begin{document}
aöz \foo aöz
\end{document}
```

generates what I expect, first umlaut missing as expected, too:

```
U+0061(a) U+007a(z) U+0020(space) U+0061(a) U+00f6(ö) U+007a(z)
```

but

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
aöz \fontspec{Cambria} aöz
\end{document}
```

generates

```
U+0061(a) U+00f6(ö) U+007a(z) U+0020 U+0061(a) U+006f(o) U+0308 U+0020 U+007a(z)
```

---

Same when using `\DeclareUTFcharacter{x00F6}{\foo}` and replacing `ö` with `\foo{}`, so I guess it's not `xunicode`'s fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27625/2356) I learned there is a `Renderer=Basic` option that causes an unknown number of [side-effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/lualatex-fontspec-and-tracking-with-microtype/27625#comment54291_27625).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}
\begin{document}
aöz \fontspec{Cambria} aöz ffi
\end{document}
```

The font doesn't seem to use ligatures anyway, where I want to use special features like `VerticalPosition=Numerator` [for vulgar fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70527/2356), I can just switch to `Renderer=Full`.

A way to keep it from messing around in my unicode while keeping all functionality would be better though…

---

I've been using the Basic renderer since and it seems to support the font's built in ligatures after all (for Cambria look at `ti`), no TeX-ligatures like `---` for dashes though, need to enter those as unicode `—`