# package siunitx doesnt work with option

Tags: siunitx

I'm using the package `siunitx` for unit-typesetting.
In particular I wanted this expression:

```
\SI[per=frac,fraction=nice]{2}{\celsius\per\kilo\metre}
```

unfortunately I get many errors like:

```
siunitx error: version-1-option
version 1 option 'per' detected
```

Similarly for fraction

Without the option part it works:

```
\SI{2}{\celsius\per\kilo\metre}
```

I'm thinking that is because I'm not using latin but utf8 (inputenc) encoding, but not sure?!
Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The names of options in `siunitx` changed a lot between versions 1 and 2, and you are using the names from version 1, while you have version 2 installed. In version 2.x of `siunitx` you should use `per-mode=fraction`, not `per=frac`. Similarly you should use `fraction-function=\sfrac` instead of `fraction=nice`.  `\usepackage{xfrac}` is also required.

(Addendum: clemens points out in a comment below that the `nice` option may have been referring to the `nicefrac` package and its `\nicefrac` macro. The output is similar,  if you prefer `nicefrac`, use `\usepackage{nicefrac}` instead of loading `xfrac`, and use `fraction-function=\nicefrac`.)

The manual can be found at for example: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}

\SI[per-mode=fraction,fraction-function=\sfrac]{2}{\celsius\per\kilo\metre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: do u have the manual for version 2?

Comment: I only found: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf

Comment: oh and just by chance... what is the syntax for: [tophrase=dots] or dash for example?

Comment: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf (or CTAN). You may have it on your system as well, try `texdoc siunitx` from a command prompt/terminal,

Comment: @Diger `range-phrase=--` for an en dash. Probably `\dots` instead of `--` for dots.

Comment: BTW: using ur proposal with /sfrac it is telling me: Font shape OT1/cmr/m/n in size 4.19998 not available. size <5> substituted on input like 66 as a warning.

Comment: @Diger Depends on font setup I think, see [How to remove the warnings "Font shape \`OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available" and "Size substitutions with differences" in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087) If you want to more specific advice, please post a new question.

Comment: Are you sure `nice` referred to the `xfrac` package and not to the [`nicefrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) package and its `\nicefrac` command? (Of course `xfrac` allows for customization so it offers more flexibility…)

Comment: @clemens Ehm, no, I'm not. Had forgotten the existence of that one.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. which reminds of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43119/ and makes me wonder if Todd ever finished his package… :)

Comment: Is there way of doing the other way around using `siunitx`? Let's say I want to type `1/2 kg`.  Can I combine `\nicefrac` or `\sfrac` with `siunitx`?

Comment: @Gagik Don't know offhand, and can't check right now. I suggest look in the manual first, and ask a new question second.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I didn't find anything in the manual. I'll post a separate question later today.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the v1 options with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI[per=frac,fraction=nice]{2}{\celsius\per\kilo\metre}

\end{document}
```

or could supply a v1 option at load time so the file works with both v1 and v2, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[per = frac]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI[per=frac,fraction=nice]{2}{\celsius\per\kilo\metre}

\end{document}
```

However, I would strongly recommend using the v2 options as detailed by [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327860/73): there are good reasons for the option name changes.