# Redefine \frac with Italic Numbers

Tags: math-mode, italic, fractions, fourier

I'd like to get fractions as they appear below (from [Improved kerning in fractions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/improved-kerning-in-fractions)):

[image]

However, my current code typesets them as follows:

[image]

Here is a MWE that reproduces these fractions.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathit}{T1}{fut\mathfamilyextension}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    1\frac{1}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I have not been able to find the way of making the fractions look as fancy as I desire. Basically:

1. Reduce spacing between numerator and the bar; and reduce spacing between denominator and the bar.
2. Change the alignment such that it does not look as weird as it currently does.

**Does anyone know how to re-define fractions such that they look as I want?** Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap `1\textstyle\frac{\,1}{\!\!1}` into some kind of macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. However, I must admit that I wouldn't know how to do that you propose. Moreover, I'd like all fractions of my document (and not only this one in particular) to look fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISED APPROACH**

`\itfrac` shown in `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathit}{T1}{fut\mathfamilyextension}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`5}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\itfrac[2]{\mathchoice
  {{\textstyle\frac{\,\displaystyle#1}{\!\!\displaystyle#2}}}
  {{\frac{\,\scriptstyle#1}{\!\!\scriptstyle#2}}}
  {{\frac{\,\scriptscriptstyle#1}{\!\!\scriptscriptstyle#2}}}
  {{\frac{\,\scriptscriptstyle#1}{\!\!\scriptscriptstyle#2}}}
}
\begin{document}
\centering
\[
    1\itfrac{1}{1} + \itfrac{12}{24} = \itfrac{250}{100}
\]
\[\textstyle
    1\itfrac{1}{1} + \itfrac{12}{24} = \itfrac{250}{100}
\]
\[\scriptstyle
    1\itfrac{1}{1} + \itfrac{12}{24} = \itfrac{250}{100}
\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle
    1\itfrac{1}{1} + \itfrac{12}{24} = \itfrac{250}{100}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible the `\itfrac` macro can be simplified as

```
\newcommand\itfrac[2]{\mathchoice
  {{\textstyle\frac{\,\displaystyle#1}{\!\!\displaystyle#2}}}
  {\frac{\,#1}{\!\!#2}}
  {\frac{\,#1}{\!\!#2}}
  {\frac{\,#1}{\!\!#2}}
}
```

It works the same in this MWE, but I am not 100% sure whether that would be the case for all use cases.

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

To elaborate on a comment made (though not really an answer, per se, this is what I was indicating..., calling it `\itfrac`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathit}{T1}{fut\mathfamilyextension}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`5}
\newcommand\itfrac[2]{\textstyle\frac{\,#1}{\!\!#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    1\itfrac{1}{1} + \itfrac{12}{24} = \itfrac{250}{100}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely! Is there any way of reducing the vertical space without using `\textstyle`? I'm asking because `\textstyle` reduces the size of the numbers as well; and I'd like to avoid that. Maybe `\raisebox`?

Comment: @Héctor Please see my edit

Comment: The edit is perfect and the output looks exactly as desired. Hence, answer accepted. Thanks a lot.