# angled fraction like superscript

Tags: positioning, typography

I would like to draw a fraction like symbol that looks similar to `\frac{a}{b}` BUT is angled so that the a is higher than the b and the slash is angled. Sort of like a `%` sign but not as drastic. Not sure if this character will come out properly: `½` but it looks similar to that.

I would like some way to control the angle of the slash and the angle of anti-diagonal(the line drawn through the center of gravities of the upper and lower numbers). The "anti-diagonal" of the `%` sign has a very similar angle to that of the slash and for my purposes it looks too "upright".

I would also like to "nest" the fractions so but not have the size change(or make it optional). Something like a/b/c with all the slashes and letters the same size.

[frac http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/9l2x7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/9l2x7.jpg)

There are four quantities I would like to control. The slash length and angle and the anti-diagonal angle and the letter separation. I would like to use this similar to a frac.

I don't mind having less control but basically looking for something that looks visually correct.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I would even go as far as saying: exact duplicate that should be merged? "I don't mind having less control but basically looking for something that looks visually correct." really minimalizes the differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a version using `tikz`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Currently several macros are defined to allow for tweaking:

  1. `\TextScale`
  2. `\SlashAngle`
  3. `\SlashScale`

### Further Enhancements:

- This has an issue that you can not nest `\Sfrac`.
- Use `pgfkeys` to allow tweaking of the applied styles via the optional first parameter of `\Sfrac` which is unused as of yet.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\TextScale}{0.75}
\newcommand*{\SlashAngle}{45}
\newcommand*{\SlashScale}{1.5}

\newlength{\NeumeratorXShift}
\newlength{\DenomiatorXShift}
\newlength{\NeumeratorYShift}
\newlength{\DenomiatorYShift}

\tikzset{Slash/.style={scale=\SlashScale, rotate=\SlashAngle}}
\tikzset{Neumerator/.style={scale=\TextScale, xshift=-\NeumeratorXShift, yshift=\NeumeratorYShift, inner sep=0, outer sep=0}}
\tikzset{Denominator/.style={scale=\TextScale, xshift=\DenomiatorXShift, yshift=-\DenomiatorYShift, inner sep=0, outer sep=0}}
\newcommand{\Sfrac}[2]{%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\NeumeratorXShift}{0.1em+0.5*\widthof{$#1$}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\DenomiatorXShift}{0.1em+0.5*\widthof{$#2$}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\NeumeratorYShift}{0.2ex+0.5*\heightof{$#1$}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\DenomiatorYShift}{0.2ex+0.5*\heightof{$#2$}}%
    \tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.09ex, baseline, yshift=0.6ex] 
        \draw [Slash] (-0.5,0.0) -- (0.5,0)
        node  [Neumerator ] at (0,0) {$#1$}
        node  [Denominator] at (0,0) {$#2$};
}%

\begin{document}
    $\frac{a}{b} \quad\Sfrac{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was afraid to use tik as it might be overkill but I guess it will have to do ;)

Comment: Well I am sort of specialize in the _overkill_ solution :-). But perhaps others will come up with an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users in the comments, this is partially answered by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5-%C2%BD) and the answer is to use package xfrac, and the command is `\sfrac{...}{...}`.