# Help designing a package to use with personal notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-writing

I am attempting to typeset a notation that I use for my own work, and I am struggling to create flexible commands. The notation involves placing mathematical symbols and expressions as if on the vertices of a triangular grid, and then using these objects in equations, resulting in images like these:

[image: notation]

[image: notation1]

[image: notation2]

[image: notation3]

Until now I have been fiddling with `tikzpicture` and painstakingly adjusting node positions until it looks right, but I want to create some commands or a package that would allow me to select the structure, like `twoOverThree` in the fourth image, and input the arguments `{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}` whether they are single letters or slightly more complicated expressions. Any advice? The `tikzpicture` strategy failed to work generally because adjustments in node positioning were always necessary depending on the arguments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX :) Would a syntax like `\WeirdNotation{2/3:a,b,c,d,e}` work for you? Can you show us how you currently make the expressions? (That way, we won't have to re-invent the wheel, here. This is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) on this site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this notation can be replicated with simple `arrays`, why do you need `TikZ`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\twooverthree}[5]{
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
        &#1&&#2\\
        #3&&#4&&#5
    \end{array}}

\newcommand{\twooverone}[3]{
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
        #1&&#2\\
        &#3
    \end{array}}

\newcommand{\oneovertwo}[3]{
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
        &#1\\
        #2&&#3\\
    \end{array}}

\newcommand{\oneone}[2]{
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
        #1\\
        &#2\\
    \end{array}}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(\oneone{a}{b}\right)\left(\oneone{d}{e}\right)
\]

\[
\alpha\left(\twooverone{a}{c}{b}\right) = 
\oneovertwo{\alpha b}{\alpha c}{\alpha a}
\]

\[
\oneone{\oneone{a}{\overline{v}}}{\oneone{\overline{w}}{f}}
\]

\[
\twooverthree{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt at an elegant solution to your custom notation. This solution does not require any packages whatsoever (`amsmath` is only included in the example for the `\bar{}` command in your example equations).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\slantstack[2]{%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{$#1$}%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{$#2$}}

\newcommand\tristack[3]{%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{$#1$}\kern.5ex%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{$#2$}%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{$#3$}}

\newcommand\invtristack[3]{%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{$#1$}%
    \kern.5ex\raisebox{-1.25ex}{$#2$}%
    \kern.5ex\raisebox{1.25ex}{$#3$}}

\newcommand\quadstack[4]{%
    \raisebox{4.25ex}{$#1$}%
    \kern-.5ex\raisebox{1.25ex}{$#2$}%
    \kern-.5ex\raisebox{-1.25ex}{$#3$}%
    \kern-.5ex\raisebox{-4.25ex}{$#4$}}

\newcommand\twooverthree[5]{%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{#1}%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{#2}%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{#3}%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{#4}%
    \raisebox{-1.25ex}{#5}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{Five basic commands:}\\\hline\\
            \texttt{\textbackslash slantstack}&
            \texttt{\textbackslash tristack}&
            \texttt{\textbackslash invtristack}&
            \texttt{\textbackslash quadstack}&
            \texttt{\textbackslash twooverthree}\\
            \slantstack{a}{b}&
            \tristack{a}{b}{c}&
            \invtristack{a}{b}{c}&
            \quadstack{a}{b}{c}{d}&
            \twooverthree{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}\\\\
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{Identical function in and out of math mode:}\\\hline\\
            $\slantstack{a}{b}$&
            $\tristack{a}{b}{c}$&
            $\invtristack{a}{b}{c}$&
            $\quadstack{a}{b}{c}{d}$&
            $\twooverthree{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}$\\\\
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{Works properly with \texttt{\textbackslash left} \& \texttt{\textbackslash right} commands:}\\\hline\\
            $\left(\slantstack{a}{b}\right)$&
            $\left(\tristack{a}{b}{c}\right)$&
            $\left(\invtristack{a}{b}{c}\right)$&
            $\left(\quadstack{a}{b}{c}{d}\right)$&
            $\left(\twooverthree{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}\right)$\\\\
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{Your equations:}\\\hline\\
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\left(\slantstack{a}{b}\right)\left(\slantstack{d}{e}\right)$
            \hfill $\alpha\left(\invtristack{a}{b}{c}\right) = \tristack{\alpha c}{\alpha b}{\alpha a}$
            \hfill \quadstack{a}{\bar{v}}{\bar{w}}{\text{f}}
            \hfill \twooverthree{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This answer uses only basic `\raisebox` and `\kern` commands, so it works nicely in every use-case I thought of and aligns and spaces well with surrounding text and equations. This should also work flawlessly with different font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In order:

1. This can be done using the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83041/4778). You would need to make line white.
2. You could use matrices here or set a `\newcommand` (I'm working on it).
3. This can be done with a foreach, only two lines of code (I don't know those letters with the above line but you get it):

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm, y=5mm]

   \foreach \y/\letter [count=\x from 0] in {5/a,4/$v$,3/$w$,2/f}{
       \node at (\x,\y) {\letter};
   }   

   \end{tikzpicture} 
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Same as number 3, can be done in a foreach (maybe even simpler than how I did it):

   [image]

   ```
    \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \foreach \y/\letter [count=\x from 0] in {0/a,1/b,0/c,1/d,0/e}{
    \node at (\x,\y) {\letter};
    }  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Try out `\bar{v}` :)

Answer (score 0):

These are trivial to set up with `stackengine` macros (original answer) and even easier still with the `tabstackengine` package (revised answer).  However, I don't feel I have enough info to set up macro shortcuts, since I don't know the full extent of the desired syntax.

Since many of your data items were in upright (non-math) font, I made the default settings to be that way.  If the items in your notation are generally math items, just issue `\stackMath` in the preamble, and the stacks will assume the arguments are math mode.

**REVISED ANSWER**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\Bigl( \tabbedstackanchor{a&}{&b}\Bigr)
\Bigl( \tabbedCenterstack{d&\\&e}\Bigr)
\]

\[
\alpha\Bigl( \tabbedstackanchor{a&&c}{&b&} \Bigr) = 
  \tabbedstackanchor{&$\alpha$b&}{$\alpha$c&&$\alpha$a}
\]

\[
\tabbedCenterstack{a&&&\\&$\bar v$&&\\&&$\bar w$&\\&&&f} = 0
\]

\[
\tabbedstackanchor{&b&&d&}{a&&c&&e}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (`stackengine`)

In the MWE below, I show various ways to get the results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\Bigl( \stackanchor{a~~}{~~b}\Bigr)
\Bigl( \Centerstack{d~~\\~~e}\Bigr)
\]

\[
\alpha\Bigl( \stackanchor{a~~c}{b} \Bigr) = 
  \stackanchor{$\alpha$b}{$\alpha$c~~~$\alpha$a}
\]

\[
\makebox[7ex]{%
\tllap[.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap\relax]{\tllap{a}$\bar v$}\brlap[.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap\relax]{$\bar w$\brlap{f}}
}  = 0
\]

\[
\stackanchor{b~~d}{a~~c~~e}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]