# Is there a way to decrease the row separation in arrays?

Tags: spacing, arrays

I would like all the arrays I generate in a document, using the normal array environment, to have slightly smaller distance between rows, but the same column separation. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Strange, usually the requirement is to increase that distance. Can you tell something more?

Comment: It is related to another question I asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245858/help-designing-a-package-to-use-with-personal-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version: Using `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` command from `etoolbox` and redefining the `\arraystretch` there

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{array}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}%
}



\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't affect `matrix` and similar environments of `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg... which weren't mentioned so far ...

Comment: Just additional information. LaRiFaRi's method does affect `matrix`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by redefining the `array` environment. However, I would not recommend this. You could place the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}` locally when ever it is needed or you introduce a new environment `myArray` with all the tweaks you like.

But here is, what you asked for:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\let\oldarray\array
\let\endoldarray\endarray
\renewenvironment{array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}\oldarray}{\endoldarray}
% you may remove the .5 by any value between 0 and 1 if you want to decrease

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach will also effect all the matrices defined by `amsmath` or `mathtools`. It will, however, not effect the tables you might have. For this you could just put `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}` in the preamble.

Comment: Why not just doing `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}` in the preamble?

Comment: @egreg I did not want to modify tabulars