# Fraction whose items are words

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I have troubles writing a fraction whose items are words not numbers.

In a nutshell I should write:

```
minaccia/vulnerabilità   --> this is the numerator
---------------------- 
contromisure             --> this is the denominator
```

I simply do this, but it doesn't work.

```
\[
\frac{minaccia/vulnerabilit\'a}{contromisure} 
\]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: thanks a lot..What should I do in order to solve the problem?..grazie

Comment: Also, please clarify the question. It's hard to tell what you're exactly asking for.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83052/4012

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I typeset arbitrary fractions like the standard symbol for .5 = ½?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should load the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and use `\text{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{\sin^2y+\cos^2z} \qquad 
  \frac{\text{minaccia/vulnerabilit\`a}}{\text{contromisure}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\mbox{...}` or `\textrm{...}`, but these won't scale when used inside exponents the way `\text{...}` does.