# Text-mode in fractions?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I want to have written words in a fraction but to have them in correct fraction form and not crude-looking. So, I have;

```
$\displaystyle\frac{Actual Value of Production}{Demand}$ x $100$
```

But it makes the text appear in math-mode so all italics with no spaces and looks awful. If I remove the `$` it just won't appear.

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84155/15925

Comment: why isn't the  x  in math mode? `...mand} \times 100$`

Comment: see also [how to place text on fraction for accounting formulas?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/how-to-place-text-on-fraction-for-accounting-formulas)

Answer (score 20):

another possibility, requiring `amsmath` is this:

```
\[
 \frac{\text{Actual Value of Production}}{\text{Demand}} \times 100
\]
```

[image]

since it's unlikely to be embedded in text, using "display" coding is preferable to the inline `$...$` input.

warning:  `\text` will follow the style of the surrounding text, so if this is
included within the statement of a theorem, it will be set in italic.  in such a
situation, it's better to use `\textrm`.

Answer (score 14):

If you're going to be writing a lot of fractions this way, you should define your own macro:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\textfrac[2]{
  \frac{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}
}
```

Then you can just write `$\textfrac{Top}{Bottom}$` and it will print the words in the current text style.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$\displaystyle\frac{\mbox{Actual Value of Production}}{\mbox{Demand}}$ x $100$
```

Comment: I'll also change the "x" by `\times`, something like this:

`$\displaystyle\frac{\mbox{Actual Value of Production}}{\mbox{Demand}} \times 100$`

If the answer is correct, please mark it as correct

Comment: `\text` is actually preferred to `\mbox`, since it is more conscientious in preserving font styles.

Comment: Also, for short inline formulas, one can use the more convenient command `\dfrac{}{}`, also from `amsmath`, instead of `\displaystyle\frac{}(}`.