# Modifying fraction macro for in-line text and exponents

Tags: macros, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, fractions

There's an amazing fraction macro [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83052/41981)* for `FontSpec` with LuaLaTeX (*: that would be the second macro in that answer, called `\unifrac`, which I like better than the first "macro"/ using the `frac` feature), but it only works if the font you're using has OpenType features `dnom` and `numr`. The font that I use, MinionMath (used with `unicode-math`, which requires `FontSpec`), does not have these features for anything beyond numbers (many fonts don't), and even fonts that have these features for letters don't have it for Greek letters.

To be honest, that macro looks absolutely beautiful for many fractions that I use for in-line text and exponents, but I wish I could use it for things other than numbers. I'm aware of the `\sfrac` macro which can use all letters (as well as `\nicefrac` and `\tfrac`) but I like the look of the `\unifrac` macro *much* more.

**Is there any way that I can modify `\unifrac` to *behave* like `\sfrac` in the sense that I can use it with non-number characters, but retain the look of `\unifrac`?**

I'll provide a MWE here along with pictures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Using unicode-math instead doesn't seem to make much difference 
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular} % this font has dnom and numr features; 
     % XITS Math, for example, doesn't

\newcommand{\unifrac}[2]{\mbox{% making sure we don't get a line break
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+numr}#1}%
    ⁄% That slash is U+2044 FRACTION SLASH, which has special spacing
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+dnom}#2}%
    }}

\begin{document}

This is \texttt{\unifrac:}\qquad
\unifrac{12}{14} \unifrac{31415}{27182} \unifrac{abc}{def} \unifrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\unifrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†} 
\[\left(\frac{3x}{2y}\right)^{\unifrac{3}{2}}=\unifrac{\lambda}{2x}\]\\

And this is \texttt{\sfrac:}\qquad
\sfrac{12}{14} \sfrac{31415}{27182} \sfrac{abc}{def} \sfrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\sfrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†}
\[\left(\frac{3x}{2y}\right)^{\sfrac{3}{2}}=\sfrac{\lambda}{2x}\]\\

\end{document}
```

For a font that has the `dnom` and `numr` features (for numbers), such as EB Garamond, this results in:
[image]

For a font that doesn't have these features, such as XITS Math, this results in:
[image]

Comment: What do you want: for fonts without `dnom` and `numr` features to switch to the `sfrac` style, or to make fonts that don't have those features "get" those features?

Comment: @Jon basically I want `\unifrac` to work in the same way that `\sfrac` does; i.e. if `\sfrac` can handle fonts that don't have `dnom` and `numr` features, why can't `\unifrac`?

Comment: @Jon if I had to choose between the two options, I'd say the "make fonts that don't have those features "get" them" is closest to what I'm asking. I know fonts that don't have those features simply won't work properly, I'm just trying to see how `\sfrac` works around that to handle things like Greek letters etc, and see if we can apply that "work-around" to `\unifrac` but still make sure that it retains its look.

Comment: `\unifrac` fundamentally depends on a font having the features you name. What that means is the font actually has a set of designed glyphs for the numbers you are seeing with EB Garamond. If those glyphs don't exist in the font you choose to use, then the `\unifrac` command is "too dumb" to fix the problem. The `xfrac` package, in contrast, is very sophisticated and scales things as needed or as you set in the options. What you might want to define is a command `\myunifrac` that uses `\unifrac` when the font has the features you need, and `\sfrac` when it doesn't.

Comment: Or modify/extend/design a font so it has the font features you want. Or, perhaps, use `fontspec` to fake the features you like if they ar missing. Or, someone will have a better idea (happens often around here)....

Comment: Perhaps its easier to just tweak it and make `\sfrac` look like `\unifrac` then? They look rather different so I would want to preserve the `\unifrac` look regardless, but with the functionality of `\sfrac` (maybe faking the features with `fontspec` is a good idea). Hopefully someone knows what to do :(

Comment: You can't make normal-style glyphs (such as the letters in what I'm typing right now) look like the "special glyphs" that a font may include (such as special letters designed to be written superscript or subscript).  Scaling a "g" down will usually not look like the specially designed small-subscript "g". However, you can help your case by ensuring that the font uses "lining" numbers rather than "oldstyle" ones (if the font has both types! EB Garamond does not, AFAIK, which is why `\sfrac` looks really different from `\unifrac` in your example).

Comment: As far as I can see, this really has to be a feature request to the relevant font foundry, asking them to add the additional characters you want to use. (Or, for fonts which allow it, get somebody else to provide the additions, of course.) It is a bit like comparing a fake italic with a real italic. A macro which fakes italic will work with all fonts, even ones which don't have an italic shape available. But it will never have the look of a macro which uses real italic. On the other hand, the macro which relies on real italic will just fail when that shape isn't available or use upright, say.

Comment: @jon EBGaramond12-Regular.otf certainly claims to have lining figures. (But I haven't tested it.)

Comment: Hmm, do you have any suggestions for fonts that have a good range of `dnom` and `numr` glyphs? I tried googling but nothing helpful came up; there has to be some way to look for fonts by specific features :/ I may just use a font that has all those letters available in `dnom` and `numr` for `\unifrac` instead...

Comment: On GNU/Linux you have a command `otfinfo`. So you can do `otfinfo -f <fontname>` and see what **f**eatures are available.

Comment: @cfr -- Indeed it does, as it turns out. The lack of bold (by design, I realize) means I just don't use the font.  @Alborz -- you can activate with `\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+lnum}`. This would help you make `\sfrac` look more like your `\unifrac`, but you'll still see differences.

Comment: @jon It won't give you the number of characters which are actually changed, though. I mean, it might only actually have a certain number of characters in the denominator series or whatever. If they can be accessed in the standard way, it'll still say `dnum`, I think. You could dump all the glyph names and hope they are regularly named. But this varies wildly in terms of what the regularity is. Or you can open them in FontForge and look, of course.

Comment: @cfr -- I think a (rather) full font will claim `dnom`, `numr`, and `lnum`; but then I'd certainly want to open up FontForge and see what the font actually has. If `otfinfo` lists neither of `dnom` or `numr`, then I probably skip firing up FontForge for that one....

Comment: @jon I know that feature, it only tells me which fonts have `dnom` and `numr` in general, not which glyphs are included under those features. I could open FontForge for each font I have, I just thought someone might have any good recommendations, ah well.

Comment: @Alborz -- Yeah, sorry. I don't have much call for digging around in such things (sticking, as I do, to the humanities).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenType support in TeX as of when I first wrote [`xfrac`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) in early 2004 was basically non-existent -- XeTeX hadn't even been released back then. Therefore, the package was never designed with that in mind. Besides, the fundamental purpose was to provide a way to write nice fractions for fonts that didn't include them.

The package could very likely be made OpenType aware by making a few changes as to how fonts are selected. However, you should also be able to define an instance for the font in question by using the numerator-format key to select the font. The following instance declaration will basically make \sfrac behave as you wish for your chosen variant of Garamond. This is very similar to the Janson example from the manual.

```
\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{EBGaramond12Regular(0)}{text}{
      numerator-format = {\fontspec{EBGaramond12Regular}[RawFeature=+numr]#1},
      scaling = false,
      numerator-bot-sep = 0pt,
      denominator-bot-sep = 0 pt,
      denominator-format = {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+dnom}#1}
}
```

Hope this helps,
Morten

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't work for math mode for some reason :/ if you retry the MWE everything works just as it should except for the in-line equation...

Comment: Recall that xfrac was an early experiment. In hindsight, I think I should have made different templates for math and text mode and let the document command make the choice. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

Here I create `\altfrac{}{}`.  It does not require `fontspec`, it obeys math mode, its font is larger than that of `\sfrac`, the denominator lies on the baseline, while the top of the numerator I tries to lay at the top of the normal text font.  The numbers are presented in `\footnotesize`.  The slash is a horizontally stretched `/` to give it more of the fractional slash appearance.

It's downside is that is does not work properly if the current fontsize is anything other than `\normalsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac,graphicx}

\newcommand{\altfrac}[2]{\ifmmode\def\tmp{$}\else\def\tmp{}\fi\mbox{%
    {\footnotesize \raisebox{.24\ht\strutbox}{\tmp#1\tmp}}%
    \kern-2.2pt\scalebox{1.6}[1]{/}\kern-1.8pt%⁄% That slash is U+2044 FRACTION SLASH, which has special spacing
    {\footnotesize\tmp#2\tmp}%
    }}

\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt
This is \texttt{altfrac:}\qquad
\altfrac{12}{14} \altfrac{31415}{27182} \altfrac{abc}{def} \altfrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\altfrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†} 
\[\left(\frac{3x}{2y}\right)^{\altfrac{3}{2}}=\altfrac{\lambda}{2x}\]
\qquad And here is \altfrac{x}{y} versus $\altfrac{x}{y}$\\

And this is \texttt{sfrac:}\qquad
\sfrac{12}{14} \sfrac{31415}{27182} \sfrac{abc}{def} \sfrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\sfrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†}
\[\left(\frac{3x}{2y}\right)^{\sfrac{3}{2}}=\sfrac{\lambda}{2x}\]\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `\footnotesize`, I think we could call these "only-partially-vulgar" fractions :)