# \nicefrac or \xfrac in \displaystyle

Tags: fractions, displaystyle, xfrac, nicefrac

How do I get `\nicefrac` or `\xfrac` work in `\displaystyle`, i.e., without reducing the font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative (since `\nicefrac` and `\sfrac` do not seem to be adjustable to representing digits in displaystyle)...

Adjusting my answer from [Modifying fraction macro for in-line text and exponents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290106/modifying-fraction-macro-for-in-line-text-and-exponents/291108#291108), this will also set numerator and denominator as text if called in text mode, and as math in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\altfrac}[2]{\ifmmode\def\tmp{$}\else\def\tmp{}\fi\mbox{%
    {\raisebox{.24\ht\strutbox}{\tmp#1\tmp}}%
    \kern-2.2pt\scalebox{1.6}[1.5]{/}\kern-1.8pt%
    {\tmp#2\tmp}%
    }}

\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt
This is \texttt{altfrac:}\qquad
\altfrac{12}{14} \altfrac{31415}{27182} \altfrac{abc}{def} \altfrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\altfrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†} 
\[\left(\frac{3x}{2y}\right)^{\altfrac{3}{2}}=\altfrac{\lambda}{2x}\]
\qquad And here is \altfrac{x}{y} versus $\altfrac{x}{y}$\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

WARNING: if used in inline mode, the size of the `/` will possibly cause the line spacing to temporarily adjust.  While this can be eliminated by `\smash`'ing the `\scalebox`, that could result in glyph overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\Large` before is doing the trick :

```
\text{\Large$\sfrac{1}{10}$}
```

It's not a proper solution and more just a hack since it produces a warning (Font: Size substitution...) and it's has to be manually specified.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item $\frac{1}{10} =\sfrac{1}{10}$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{10} = \text{\Large$\sfrac{1}{10}$}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And the corresponding output:

[image: sfrac with and without \Large]