# Libertine fancy fractions not working with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fractions, libertine

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Fractions=On]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
% \addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}

1/2 3/4 5/6 7/8 9/10 11/12 31415/27182 1000/1000000

\end{document}
```

Compiling with TeX Live LuaLaTeX on Lubuntu gives the following output:

[image]

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5-%c2%bd/83052#83052) answer, it should be possible to achieve this effect with Libertine. The line I commented out in the code is another method I tried, which produced the same incorrect output as shown.

Comment: Might it be the case that the`libertineotf` package provides additional code not found in the font itself? Note the difference between your code and the linked answer: You called the font directly, using `fontspec`, but the linked answer has `\usepackage{libertineotf}`.

Comment: More: The `libertineotf` package is marked as obsolete, at CTAN. But it is still available. I looked at it, and it does indeed contain some code other than just the fonts. However, you can still get fractions the hard way (not very hard) by using features such as sups and subs (or sinf) for the separate numerators and denominators. So what you need can be done, but maybe in a way different than you expected.

Comment: @RobtA Only because `libertine.sty` now handles the Unicode engines. And `libertineotf.sty` isn't only on CTAN. It is still part of the `libertine` package installed, for example, as part of TeX Live. Just it shouldn't be used for new documents.

Comment: @cfr Good clarification. I use only LuaLeTeX, and load fonts directly rather than via packages. No problem. Maybe this is the situation faced by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that I used XeLaTeX for compilation. The code does not work with LuaLaTeX.**

I get warnings, but the output looks as it looks in the linked answer.

Although `libertineotf.sty` is obsolete, this is only because `libertine.sty` now handles both the unicode engines and (to some limited extent) the traditional ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}

1/2 3/4 5/6 7/8 9/10 11/12 31415/27182 1000/1000000

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine fractions]

If you don't wish to use the `libertine` package for some reason, you can do exactly the same with `fontspec`. As a bonus, I don't get the warnings mentioned above in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Fractions=On]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}

1/2 3/4 5/6 7/8 9/10 11/12 31415/27182 1000/1000000

\end{document}
```

That is, simply uncommenting the line produces what I understand to be the desired output.

Comment: It is my understanding that the "RawFeature" is encoded in the accompanying *.sty file, rather than in the *.otf fonts. Perhaps this is confusing to those of us who approach fontspec from the direction of understanding fonts, rather than understanding TeX packages.

Comment: @RobtA Why do you think that?

Comment: @RobtA There is no mention of `frac` in `libertine.sty`. `RawFeature` allows the use of features supported by the font, but with no `fontspec` interface.

Comment: @RobtA Please see edited answer above.

Comment: You are correct! I learned something new. I looked at the original fonts in FontForge. Key word is "original" since I have an edited local version.  I am confusing "how fontspec selects font features" with "how fonts have features." I hope that all of this is not confusing the OP.

Comment: I'm utterly baffled. Compiling the exact, verbatim code does not work for me.

Comment: @KevinKeith Note that the code does not seem to work at all with LuaLaTeX. I used XeLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr any idea as to why? I'm confused what's going on with this

Comment: @KevinKeith I asked on the context list. The feature isn't currently supported in the fontloader code of context (and so it doesn't work with lualatex either).