# Notation of Ring Factor

Tags: amsmath

I can't make this expression

[image]

Anyone can help me to make this expression?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I normally use `$S/I$`. I have never seen anyone use a "large" `/`, and I would advise against it. This said, if you really want this then you could use something like `\newcommand\Quot{{\mathop{\mbox{\large/}}}}` after which you could write $S\Quot I$.

Comment: This is similar to [How do I typeset arbitrary fractions like the standard symbol for .5 = ½?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3372/5764) and is probably independent of the fact that this points to some mathematical notation.

Comment: MS Word also has this kind of large `/` (sometimes I like that `:)`).

Comment: Don't; I've never seen an algebra paper or book using that; the plain `$R/I$` is what's generally used.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a dedicated package (requires `amssymb`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{faktor} %

\begin{document} 

This is a typical factor ring: $\faktor{S}{I}$. 

\end{document}
```

[image]