# IBM Plex text fractions with ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, context

I want to typeset text fractions with potentially arbitrary text instead of just numbers. A solution was presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5-%C2%BD) and this is my ConTeXt implementation:

```
\usetypescriptfile[ibmplex]
\setupbodyfont[ibmplex, 12pt]
\definefontfeature[numr][default][numr=yes]
\definefontfeature[dnom][default][dnom=yes]
\definehighlight[textnumr][default][style={\feature[+][numr]}]
\definehighlight[textdnom][default][style={\feature[+][dnom]}]

\definefontfeature[frac][default][frac=yes]
\definehighlight[textfrac][default][style={\feature[+][frac]}]

\def\fancyfrac#1#2{\textnumr{#1} \Uchar"2044 \textdnom{#2}}

\starttext
\fancyfrac{1}{8} % The 1 is not properly kerned
\textfrac{1/8} % Proper kerning
\stoptext
```

However, it seems that the `numr` feature is not working properly. In the log there is a line that reads:

```
system          > error: invalid parent default for textnumr, default defined too (best check it)
```

For the record I'm using the latest `lmtx` on Ubuntu 18.04. Does anyone know what the issue here is?

**[EDIT]:** I hacked together a solution based on the answer provided by Wolfgang that appears to work very well (even though I have no idea why):

```
\setupbodyfont [ibmplex]

\definefontfeature [f:numr] [numr=yes]
\definefontfeature [f:dnom] [dnom=yes]
\definefontfeature [f:frac] [frac=yes]
\define[2]\AugmentedVulgarFraction{\feature[+][f:frac]\vulgarfraction{{\feature[+][f:numr]#1}\:}{\:\feature[+][f:dnom]#2}}
```

**[EDIT 2]:** Upon further discussion with Wolfgang I ended up using the following macro:

```
\definesymbol[vulgarfraction][\textfraction]
\define[2]\TextFraction{\chardef\vulgarfractionmethod2\vulgarfraction{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: The change the method for `\vulgarfraction` use `\setconstant\vulgarfractionmethod=2` (the `=` is optional) or `\setconstant\vulgarfractionmethod\plustwo` (\plustwo = 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small space between the numerator and the slash appears because you have a space there in your definition for the `\fancyfrac` command.

```
\def\fancyfrac#1#2{\textnumr{#1} \Uchar"2044 \textdnom{#2}}
```

When you remove the space the gap disappears.

```
\def\fancyfrac#1#2{\textnumr{#1}\textfraction\textdnom{#2}}
```

The error message appears because your `highlight` defintions inherit it's values from the `default` instance but no instance with this name exists, when you change it to

```
\definehighlight [textnumr] [..,..=..,..]
```

the message disappears.

You can save a few lines when you drop the `highlight` commands and apply the features in the fraction command, there is also no need to inherit the `default` features for the numerator and denominator.

```
\setupbodyfont [ibmplex]

\definefontfeature [f:numr] [numr=yes]
\definefontfeature [f:dnom] [dnom=yes]

\define[2]\TextFraction
  {{\feature[+][f:numr]#1}%
    \textfraction
   {\feature[+][f:dnom]#2}}

\starttext

0123456789/0123456789

{\setfractions 0123456789/0123456789}

\TextFraction{1}{2}

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer Wolfgang! But as I said in the question what I'm more interested in is the case `\TextFraction{дин}{kg}` which is still not typeset correctly.

Comment: @blaze The `numr` and `dnom` features are for numbers only. When you need fractions which work with text you can try the `subs` and `sups` features but the results are font dependent. A alternative to opentype features is the `\vulgarfraction{...}{...}` command but the spacing isn't perfect but you can ask on the ConTeXt mailing list to fix it.

Comment: Actually, in the answer I linked in my question the exact behavior was demonstrated with `numr` and `dnom`. I'm reopening my question.

Comment: 1. Not all features are supported by each font and sometimes a font covers only a limited character set with a feature. 2. Can you reproduce the LaTeX example? I tries the mentioned fonts but wasn't able to get the same results but I don't know which version they used.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the results either, because I don't have XeTeX, or LuaLaTeX installed (long story short I'm running everything on a cloud VM and I'm only using ConTeXt standalone). But when I run `mtxrun --script font --list --info ibmplexserif` I get that all `otf` features are supported for scripts `cyrl`, `dflt` and `latin` and language `dflt`. Is there a way to know for sure if this is supported for non numerals? What do you think about my hack?

Comment: @blaze The feature setting in your `\AugmentedVulgarFraction` are useless because the have no effect (the `frac` setting is even worse because you apply it to all text which comes after the command) and the small text is a result of the `\vulgarfraction` command. All you did was to add space around the slash (which can be changed with `\definesymbol[vulgarfraction][\textfraction]`) but this is something which should be fixed in the ConTeXt core.