# Use XeLaTeX in Texmaker instead of pdfLaTeX

Tags: xetex, texmaker

I use TeX Live 2010 and my editor is Texmaker Bidi. It was working probably good but from 2 months ago I've encountered with the error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

when I'm trying to load `xepersian` LaTeX. 
but I do not know how can I change pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX.

---

This is the second edit of my question . 
 the code is :

```
 ‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{pstricks}‎
‎\usepackage{‎pst‎-‎bezier}‎
‎‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
 ‎\settextfont{XB Zar}‎
 ‎\setlatintextfont{Junicode}‎
 ‎\setdigitfont{XB Zar}‎
 ‎\begin{document}‎
 ‎!‎سلام دنیا‎‎
‎\begin{pspicture}(‎3‎,3)‎
‎\psbcurve(1,2)(5,7)(2,2)(12,3)‎
‎\end{pspicture}‎
‎
‎\end{document}
```

but the output does not include the shapes .

Comment: See TeXmakers's online manual in: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION25

Comment: I would prefer lualatex. I used xelatex in the past (I needed some special fonts and lualatex wasn't stable enough). But now I'm switching to luaLaTeX, and I think lualatex will be the future.

Comment: related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/moving-from-pdflatex-to-xetex-what-do-i-need-to-know, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex

Comment: Your TeX Live folder path must contain no space character.

Comment: I had similar problem [Ubuntu 2012 + texlive 2012]. Using xelatex in Terminal everything is fine, but in Texmaker, nothing happended and 100% CPU occupation. Tried updmap
and sudo updmap Problem still persists.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Added Update to the existing answer:

**For those using Texmaker Version's > 3.5.1**

From Texmaker Version `3.5.1` onwards [`xelatex` support has been added](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) . Download [Latest version of Texmaker: 4.1.1 dated Jan 3 2014](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) that has `xelatex` support in standard commands like shown below.

[image: standard commands in texmaker]

> xelatex has been added to the standard commands (with a new "quick compilation" mode : xelatex + view pdf)

Hence there might be no need of Configuring Texmaker for xelatex with `User Commands.

**Note:** From Texmaker Version `4.1` onwards [LuaLaTeX support also has been added](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)

**For those using Texmaker Version's < `3.5`**

You will have to define a custom command in Texmaker - it's fairly simple.

Open the **User → User Commands** menu and select **Edit User Commands**. This will bring up a dialog box like so:

[image: xelatex custom command]

Add a menu item name and set the command to `xelatex %`

Hit okay and you will now be able to run the newly created command from the **User → User Commands** menu or by hitting `alt-shift-Fn` where *n* is the number of the command. So, for instance, `alt-shift-F1` will run the command I have defined here. This may be Windows specific. It will also appear on the build menu in the toolbar, underneath everything else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tired this but I encountered another problem : the output will be a blank page . I change the users part as u said to :xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %.tex   , but it cause me face with a blank output !!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Negin - I would need to see your input to be able to tell you why this is happening. Try running xelatex on a minimal document and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: ‎@ Richard -I included the code in the new edit of my question . I would really appreciate it if you help me .

Comment: @Negin - I had a look at your code - there are many odd non-printing characters (which get translated to `ÔÇÄ`) at the beginning and end of your lines as well as inside the `pst-bezier` import - I had to remove them to get xelatex to behave. I imagine they might be text direction characters based on the fact you're typing in persian. Anyhow, that's stopping xelatex from running in the first instance. I removed them and things seem to work, except I do not have the XB Zar font you are using. The exclamation point does however turn up between the two persian words ('hello world'?)

Comment: @Negin - What text editor are you using and what keyboard language is your operating system set to? That would be quite useful in working out what's going on. [Here's the output I got from xelatex, btw](http://i.imgur.com/qe3z4.png)

Comment: @ Richard -the problem is this : if I want to type in persian and use many packages I should use xepersian package and it does work with xelatex but when I change the configuration in welatex I encounter with no error but the output does not include the shapes which I've drawn by pstricks . My editor is texmaker  , the operating languages are English and Persian , and the font is not important you can change it into times new roman or tahoma . . . .

Comment: @Richard-the output which you get is what I exactly want to take , but I have no idea why I cannot have shapes !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Negin - Try running `xelatex` on your .tex file in a console, and see what the output looks like. It is likely that your file is producing errors, but that it's being ignored by texmaker, due to the fact that you are using the `nonstopmode` flag.

Comment: @Negin: It is very simple why you can not get shapes. You are using TeXLive 2010 and pstricks is broken for xelatex in your version of TeXLive. Many people including myself suggested upgrading your TeX distribution to TeXLive 2011 but I do not know why you asking one question in many places when you already have got several answers!

Comment: @Vafa I had many issues with upgrading my TeXLive as many others and I did ask this question here to see whether there is another way for solving this problem or not  .

Comment: Thank you! Does anyone know how to get this working in TexStudio? I'm getting the error "Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function."