# XeLaTeX hang on Defining document command \newfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 118

Tags: xetex, compiling, texmaker

I am using TexMaker 4.0 on a Windows 7 (64bit) machine, with MiKTeX v2.9, and I am trying to compile [this template](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/3/cv_3.tex) (with no modifications) with XeLaTeX using the instructions contained in the first answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32020/use-xelatex-in-texmaker-instead-of-pdflatex).

It hangs when I attempt to run the custom user command `xelatex %` (% is the name of the current file). The last few lines of the log file before it hangs are the following:

```
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 118.
.........................
```

Running `xelatex file` in the console yields the following output:

```
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl
                                fontspec/Ligatures/Historical
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

?
```

Comment: It probably doesn't hang but is looking for a font (e.g. Hoefler Text normally doesn't exist on windows). Be patient and wait for the error message.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I have left it running for over half an hour and still it does not appear to be doing anything - no new lines have been added to the log. I am pretty confident it is in some sort of loop, or encountered a barrier it cannot get past.

Comment: Can you tell what TeX distribution you're running? Try updating it to the most recent version of all packages.

Comment: Installing the fonts 'Hoefler', 'Andale' and 'Zapfino' (already had 'Gill Sans') has not affected the line the log stops on.

Comment: Found alternative implementation of the same template that does not require XeLaTeX to compile.

Comment: The error message about `\c_keys_code_root_tl` indicates that your fontspec version is outdated. Run the update manager (in admin mode if you have a multi user installation as your fontspec resides in the main root).

Answer (score 2):

The error message about `\c_keys_code_root_tl` indicates that your fontspec version is outdated. Run the update manager (in admin mode if you have a multi user installation as your fontspec resides in the main root).