# XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX + fontspec "font-not-found" in CV template

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, texmaker

I am trying to compile a CV template using XeLateX. I have always used Pdflatex, so I created a XeLaTeX command as described here: [Use XeLaTeX in Texmaker instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32020/use-xelatex-in-texmaker-instead-of-pdflatex). I then downloaded the font and installed it (as described here: http://www.fontspring.com/support/installing/how-do-i-install-fonts-on-my-mac). I now get the error "Error : could not start the command" instead of "process exited normally" and in the log file the error ist "font-not-found." when running XeLaTeX (in Texmaker). At the same time the font appears in finder as well as in Textedit, OpenOffice etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font
```

Comment: With the latest versions of Texmaker, you don't have to create a special command to use XeLaTeX. There is a "quick build" mode for "xelatex+View Pdf" (Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Quick Build)

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use, and which vintage are XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX programs you use. For what it's worth, under MacTeX2013, your code -- suitably augmented to produce output -- runs fine.

Comment: Where did you obtain the font and which version did you use? For example, if you obtained it from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html, you would want to download the OpenType or TTF fonts (probably OpenType) - **not** the Type1, which almost certainly won't work at all with XeLaTeX.