# How to easily update Texmaker to latest version?

Tags: texmaker

I currently work with Texmaker 3.5 on Windows 7, but after reading a comment on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134695/39246) question I decided to update my version of Texmaker.

However, the only way I found to do this is by uninstalling my current version and getting a recent one the Internet.

Is it the only way to upgrade my Texmaker? What about my User Commands, current settings and everything? Is there a way to automatically update Texmaker?

Comment: Are you using Linux? If yes, just download the new release and install it. It will overwrite the old one.

Comment: Edited to add windows 7

Comment: So, in this case you have to download the new version and install it.

Comment: Uninstalling it leaves all user settings on the computer, so the new install will find them.

Comment: You probably can export all of your user settings and then re-import them

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/backup-of-user-defined-entries-of-autocompletion-in-texmaker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing up the above comments with relevant info/Links to a full answer:

- As recommended by Texmaker author, It is prefered to [Notes: - Uninstall first all previous version before installing a new one](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux) to avoid any conflicts with existing one atleast on Linux.
- On Windows, Uninstall using [`control panel`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uninstall-change-program#uninstall-change-program=windows-vista) to remove the existing version. On Ubuntu Linux [uninstall](http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Ubuntu-Software) with `Synaptic Package manager` or `sudo apt-get --purge remove texmaker` . Never install `texmaker-data` package on Linux.
- Uninstall does not remove any User Settings/Custom User Commands on both Linux and Windows since they are stored in User-profiles even after removal. But to be safe [Backup of user-defined entries of autocompletion in Texmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81858/15717) and `Options`-->`Settings File`-->`Replace the settings with a New one`.

Automatic Check for New version of Texmaker

- Starting from Texmaker version `4.0.3` [- Users can now check if a new version is available via a new option in the "Help" menu](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html). 
  i.e `Help`-->`Check Update`-->`Check for Available version` to match the latest available version.

Comment: Worked fine for me, thanks. From now on, does the automatic check also allows automatic update if a new version is found or is it only a check, as stated in the name?

Comment: @Kalissar I assume, It's only a check if a new version exists or not.

Comment: @gsamaras fixed