# Safe installation of Texmaker Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, security

Is it safe to install Texmaker from Ubuntu Software Center? It is outdated and a newer version is available from the Texmaker projekt website, but I really do not want to install software from "outside the software center". The Texmaker in the software center is in the universe repo. 
Does somebody know if texmaker opens any ports or accesses internet if I just open the installed program?

Comment: You should give the precise versions, and what you are affraid of: that Texmaker access internet, that Texmaker sends private information (=cannot be trusted), ... ?

Comment: Debian packages will always lag behind current releases of all software. For instance, on Ubuntu 14.04, only TeX Live 2013 is available.

Comment: I am afraid that it comes from universe repository and is lagging behind the current version. So my thinking is - did anybody check it after it came to the universe repository? And the other think is indead the access of the internet and if there is some kind of an old bug which is critical in this point and which is not fixed since it is an older version.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a quick look at the changelog might help you (no security issues mentioned...). You can find this here: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html. To answer your question: as far as I know TexMaker does not open ports.

If this motivates you to install the latest version anyway:

1. Download TexMaker (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux)
2. Remove previous versions: `sudo apt-get purge texmaker` (in a terminal)
3. Install TexMaker `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_*.deb`(if the deb file you've downloaded is still in the 'Downloads' folder).

Good luck!

Comment: David thanks! You can also check the automatic step here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147742/61180) for your first step!