# Problems with a template (CV front page)

Tags: templates

How to make this to look like the link? And please not make it XeLaTeX :-) [enter link description here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3865/wie-kann-ich-eine-bewerbungs-titelseite-mit-latex-gestalten)

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,mwe}
\definecolor{cvgreen}{HTML}{92D14F}
\definecolor{cvgray}{HTML}{D8E4BE}
\definecolor{cvtext}{HTML}{92909B}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % green bar
    \fill[cvgreen] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=5cm]current page.south west);
    % gray bar
    \fill[cvgray] ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
    % title and date
    \node[cvtext,right] at ([yshift=-7cm]current page.north west) {\bfseries Bewerbung als Bankkauffrau};
    \node[cvtext,above left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-9.5cm]current page.north east) {\huge\bfseries zum 01.09.2013};
    % cover photo
    \node[inner sep=0pt,below right] (image) at ([xshift=5cm,yshift=-10cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=9cm]{example-image-a}};
    % name and address
    \node[fill=white,drop shadow,align=center,text width=6.4cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below] (name) at (image.south) {\LARGE Martina Mustermann};
    \node[text width=15cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below right] at (name.south west) {\Large\obeylines%
        Musterweg 8
        81929 München
        Tel.: 01 74 / 98 98 61
        E-Mail: Martina.M@web.de
    };
    % attachments
    \node[white,text width=5cm,inner sep=0.3cm,above right] at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south west) {\large\obeylines%
        \textbf{Anlagen:}
        Lebenslauf
        Bewerbungsschreiben
        Letzte 2 Schulzeugnisse
        Praktikumsbestätigungen
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me if I use XeLaTeX.

Comment: I use LaTeX with Texmaker? What is XeLaTeX and what are I doing wrong? And how to fix it? :) ... I have just installed texlive-full and texmaker :-)

Comment: XeLaTeX is an alternative typesetting engine to LaTeX, which allows you to use system fonts. See this post on how to change the typesetting engine in Texmaker:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32020/use-xelatex-in-texmaker-instead-of-pdflatex

Alternatively, if you remove `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `\setmainfont{Calibri}`, and `\addfontfeature{Scale = 5}` it should work with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the XeLaTeX parts it works with LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,mwe}
\definecolor{cvgreen}{HTML}{92D14F}
\definecolor{cvgray}{HTML}{D8E4BE}
\definecolor{cvtext}{HTML}{92909B}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % green bar
    \fill[cvgreen] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=5cm]current page.south west);
    % gray bar
    \fill[cvgray] ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
    % title and date
    \node[cvtext,right] at ([yshift=-7cm]current page.north west) {\bfseries Bewerbung als Bankkauffrau};
    \node[cvtext,above left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-9.5cm]current page.north east) {\huge\bfseries zum 01.09.2013};
    % cover photo
    \node[inner sep=0pt,below right] (image) at ([xshift=5cm,yshift=-10cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=9cm]{example-image-a}};
    % name and address
    \node[fill=white,drop shadow,align=center,text width=6.4cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below] (name) at (image.south) {\LARGE Martina Mustermann};
    \node[text width=15cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below right] at (name.south west) {\Large\obeylines%
        Musterweg 8
        81929 München
        Tel.: 01 74 / 98 98 61
        E-Mail: Martina.M@web.de
    };
    % attachments
    \node[white,text width=5cm,inner sep=0.3cm,above right] at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south west) {\large\obeylines%
        \textbf{Anlagen:}
        Lebenslauf
        Bewerbungsschreiben
        Letzte 2 Schulzeugnisse
        Praktikumsbestätigungen
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]