# How to introduce a few lines in Bangla font in an otherwise English document in PdfLaTex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, texmaker, mac

I am writing my dissertation with TeXMaker, compiling with PDFLatex. I want to add a couple of lines in Bangla fonts on a particular page. How can I accomplish that? I am on Mac El-Capitan system. I have been able to compile a primarily Bengali document as given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex/99659#99659).

Comment: You need to tell TeXMaker to use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`.   See [Use XeLaTeX in Texmaker instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32020). You may also need to change a couple of other things in your document. See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736)

Answer (score -1):

Taken from https://methopath.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/writing-unicode-bengali-in-latex/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%
% This file is a sample tex file to illustrate use of
% XeTeX in typesetting Bengali document.
% License: GNU FDL: (C) Golam Mortuza Hossain, 2008
%
%
% Define fonts that you want to use
%

\newfontfamily\telugufont[Script=Bengali]{Arial}  %% Use appropriate Bengali Font
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{XITS}

\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguages{english}
% Lines removed to improve the code as \font is TeX Command. 
%\font\serif="FreeSerif:script=beng"
%\font\serifbb="FreeSerif:script=beng" at 24pt
%\font\deffont="FreeSerif:script=beng" at 14pt
%\font\mukti="Mukti Narrow Bold:script=beng"

%
% "script=beng" in above lines ensures that appropriate
% complex text rendering engines are used for proper
% rendering of Bengali.
%

\title{\bf\serifbb পাগলা দাশু}
\author{\bf\serif সুকুমার রায়}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\deffont %Default font used for the document
\maketitle

আমাদের স্কুলের যত ছাত্র তাহার মধ্যে এমন কেহই ছিল না, যে পাগলা দাশুকে
না চিনে। যে লোক আর কাহাকেও জানে না, সেও সকলের আগে পাগলা দাশুকে চিনিয়া
লয়। সেবার একজন নূতন দারোয়ান আসিল, একেবারে আনকোরা পাড়াগেঁয়ে লোক, কিন্তু
প্রথম যখন সে পাগলা দাশুর নাম শুনিল, তখনই সে আন্দাজে ঠিক ধরিয়া লইল যে,
এই ব্যক্তিই পাগলা দাশু। কারণ তার মুখের চেহারায়, কথাবার্তায়, চলনে চালনে
বোঝা যাইত যে তাহার মাথায় একটু 'ছিট' আছে। তাহার চোখদুটি গোল-গোল,
কানদুটা অনাবশ্যক রকমের বড়, মাথায় এক বস্তা ঝাঁকড়া চুল। চেহারাটা দেখিলেই
মনে হয়---

\vskip 10mm

% Specific font can be used for any part of the document
{\mukti বিঃদ্রঃ এই বাংলা পাতাটি লেখার জন্য XeTeX ব্যবহার করা হয়েছে।}

\end{document}
```

Adapt according to your fonts and packages

Comment: You really shouldn't use Plain TeX font selection commands in LaTeX. The correct way to load fonts with `fontspec` in  LaTeX is to use `\newfontfamily`, as in the duplicate question linked in the comments to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the point.  Firstly I am a newbie in LaTeX and I referred the blog from where I have taken this reply.  While I was searching some Indic language typesetting formats I came across this.