# How to make XeLaTeX recognize linked fonts with Windows?

Tags: fonts, xetex, windows

I can not get `fontconfig`, which XeLaTeX relies on, to recognize fonts that are in the Fonts folder as shortcuts (to fonts in other folders). `fc-cache` and `fc-list` ignore the shortcuts, which do not appear using the `dir` command.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You may modify `fonts.conf` directly.

Comment: @LeoLiu Please write a short answer.

Comment: @lockstep: done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the configuration file `fonts.conf` of `fontconfig` library.

### TeX Live

For TeX Live 2011, if you install it in e.g. `C:\texlive`, open `C:\texlive\2011\texmf-var\fonts\conf\fonts.conf`, there should be these lines:

```xml
<!--
    Find fonts in these directories

        You can add other directories if you have additional fonts.
        Example:
<dir>C:/Windows/fonts</dir>
<dir>c:/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/dnscreen/hiragino</dir>
<dir>c:/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/adobe/kozuka</dir>

-->

<dir>C:/Windows/fonts</dir>
<dir>C:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
<dir>C:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
```

You can add some lines as you wish.

### MiKTeX

If you are using MiKTeX (installed in `C:\miktex` for example), you can see `C:\miktex\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf` and follow guide lines in the comments of the file. In fact, you should then open `localfonts.conf` to see the predefined directories, and then create a `localfonts2.conf` to add your own paths.

In `fonts.conf`:

```xml
<!--
    DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
    IT WILL BE REPLACED WHEN FONTCONFIG IS UPDATED.
    LOCAL CHANGES BELONG IN 'local.conf'.

    The intent of this standard configuration file is to be adequate for
    most environments.  If you have a reasonably normal environment and
    have found problems with this configuration, they are probably
    things that others will also want fixed.  Please submit any
    problems to the fontconfig bugzilla system located at fontconfig.org

    Note that the normal 'make install' procedure for fontconfig is to
    replace any existing fonts.conf file with the new version.  Place
    any local customizations in local.conf which this file references.

    Keith Packard
-->

<!-- Font directory list -->

    <include>C:\miktex/fontconfig/config/localfonts.conf</include>
```

And this is `localfonts.conf`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! It will be replaced when MiKTeX is updated.
  Instead, edit the configuration file localfonts2.conf.
-->

<fontconfig>
<include>localfonts2.conf</include>
<dir>C:\Windows\Fonts</dir>
<dir>C:\miktex\fonts\type1</dir>
<dir>C:\miktex\fonts\opentype</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: This is not the answer I was hoping for but that is a failing of XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Emre: The problem is that *shortcuts* are different with symbolic *links*. You can also use `mklink` command for the fonts, like Linux users do. Anyway, this is how `fontconfig` library work, XeTeX could do nothing about it.

Comment: I do not understand. Windows applications don't complain about linked fonts.

Comment: @Emre: Windows applications don't use `fontconfig` library either. Windows APIs are used by Windows apps. It's quite different between how XeTeX use a font and how MS Word use a font.

Comment: @LeoLiu The placement of the fontconfig files that you described didn't apply to my MiKTeX 2.9 (Win 7-64) Admin installation, I had to change the `localfonts2.conf` file in `C:\Users\doncherry\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84223/setmainfontlinux-libertine-o-uses-pfb-files-instead-of-otf/84237#comment180978_84237. (I don't know if this'll apply to other users' systems as well, so I leave adapting the answer up to you.)

Comment: BTW as it seems, there is now a dummy `localfonts2.conf` created. I have such a file with no meaningful entries.