# Bug with XeLaTeX \setmainfont{CMU Serif} command displaying Bold/Italic/BoldItalic fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Bold/Italic/BoldItalic fonts with `\XeLaTeX`'s `\setmainfont` does not work correctly. For example (below), the `\textbf{English}` and `\textit{English}` looks like normalfont. With `\LuaLaTex` it is works fine.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}                 
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}            
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{English}\\
\texttt{English}\\
\textit{English}\\

\end{document}
```

With certain other definition

```
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunbx,
  ItalicFont=cmunti,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
]{cmunrm}
```

Both, `\XeLaTeX` and `\LuaTeX` displays fonts correctly.

I'm using WinXP SP3, Miktex 2.9 (updated)

### Some additions

I found temporary solution of the problem. I notice with the `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` `\XeLaTeX` works well. Then I install fonts from `\MikTex\fonts\opentype\public\cm-unicode\` to the `Windows\Fonts` folder.

It turns out that only `MiKTeX`'s `xelatex.exe` can see fonts from system folder, not from own folder  despite the that `LaTeX\MikTex\fontconfig\config\*fonts*.conf` are included the path to own font folders.

### Another additions

As I noticed, the `xelatex.exe` understand many Human fontfamily names from `\MikTex\fonts\opentype\public\cm-unicode\` except only CMU Serif family.

```
\setmainfont{CMU Bright}
```

displays Bold/Italic/BoldItalic fonts.

It seems, the problem localized not in the `xelatex.exe` but possible in the package `fontspec` for xelatex, or more probably, in the font files `cmun*.otf`. May be inside `cmun*.otf` there are no relations between other files, which is belong to the same family. But it is strange, the `LuaLaTeX` displays `CMU Serif` family correct.

Comment: It depends on several factors; if you've made known the fonts to your system, then the first form will work. Otherwise it won't and the second form will be necessary. What operating system are you using and what TeX distribution?

Comment: @egreg I'm using WinXP SP3, Miktex 2.9 (updated)
"if you've made known the fonts to your system" - how can I do this? And possible fonts is known for system because \LuaLaTex works

Comment: That's unfortunate, as I know nothing about MiKTeX and Windows. Maybe others will help you in sorting out the issue, that's just as I said: make the fonts known to the system.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/how-to-make-xelatex-recognize-linked-fonts-with-windows

Comment: @egreg By the way, I notice the log-file string Font shape `EU1/CMUSerif(0)/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `EU1/CMUSerif(0)/m/n' instead

Comment: That's normal: since CMU Serif isn't known to the system, it can't associate to it the boldface variant. Did you try the method suggested by Leo Liu?

Comment: @egreg  Yes, but it does no effect!

Comment: I can confirm that there is a problem. miktex/fontspec does find the normal font and the italic font but when looking for the bold font is finds (only) the regular variant: `Requested font "CMU Serif/B/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> ]^^B/MiKTeX2.9/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunrm.otf` and then is miffed that it is not a bold font. It is not related to the fonts (the problem persists after I copied the fonts from texlive). I suspect a problem with the binary (the version is slightly different to the one in texlive).

Comment: I made some additions

Comment: be careful not to have fonts in two locations. This can lead to faulty glyphs when xelatex finds the one version and xdvipdfmx the other.

Comment: I made some additions again

Comment: Last update of MikTeX (dated 1/24/2015) solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

With -up-to-date TL 2014 and `xelatex` and `lualatex`

[image]

```
*File List*
article.cls 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
expl3.sty 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer (loader)
expl3-code.tex 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def 2014/11/23 v5465 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def
xparse.sty 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontenc.sty
[ ... ]
```

You should update your system.