# My system can't find installed otf and ttf fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, texlive, opentype

I have `texlive 2019` on windows 10 OS, I tried several times to install True Type Font or Open Type Font and after installation my system couldn't find them (the problem did not occur with my previous distribution `texlive 2018`).

For example I installed Gidole font from http://gidole.github.io/ then run

```
fc-cache
```

After that

```
fc-list Gidole
```

And I don't get a result, trying to use the font with `xetex` or `luatex` do not succeed.

Comment: This produce  (first line)
`C:/WINDOWS/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1389 fonts, 0 dirs`

Comment: @cfr I have tried with `fc-cache -r --verbose` but  it doesn't  succeed.

Comment: luatex doesn't use fc-cache, you could force it to update its font cache using luaotftool

Comment: like this `luaotftools --update -f` @DavidCarlisle ?

Comment: something like that, I've hardly ever needed to run it by hand normally it runs itself if a font isn't found, but it's there if you need it, see `luaotftool --help`

Comment: when you say you installed the font, what did you do, put it in \windows\fonts ?

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: Make sure the font is installed for all users, not just one account.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you so much this solve the issue, can you add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX Live on Windows can only find fonts that are installed in system directories.  You must Install for All Users, which requires Administrator privileges.  The default installation will put them in a hidden user directory, which doesn’t work.  If you do not want to install a file system-wide as an administrator, you can instead put it in a project directory and use the `Path =` command option of `fontspec`.

You could also put it in a subdirectory of your local TeX Live directory, normally `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts`.  Re-run `fc-cache -fsv` and `luaotfload-tool -f -u -v` to update your font caches.  (I can confirm that `luaotfload` checks `texmf-local`, but I am not sure about `fc-cache`.  On the other hand, `fc-cache` checks `%WINDIR%\Fonts\Deleted` and will sometimes match a version of the font you removed instead of the one you installed to replace it.)

Having a shadow copy of the font, which might go out of date, is a bad idea.  If you reinstall a font for all users, you should remove the user-installed copy from the Fonts control panel.

A properly-configured TeX Live on Linux has no such limitation, and I am honestly not sure what the reason is for it on Windows.  The documentation for `fc-cache` and `luaotfload-tool` list options that are supposed to search local directories for fonts, but do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to file `C:\texlive\2021\texmf-var\fonts\conf\fonts.conf`:

```
<dir>C:/Users/<YourName>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts</dir>
```

Then run `fc-cache -vf` to update the font cache.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54582

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!