# Space after closing double quotes in XeLaTeX

Tags: spacing, xetex, punctuation

I'm writing some non-technical text that I'm trying to typeset using XeLaTeX. For simplicity, I'm keeping the actual text in  plain text files which after certain modifications (e.g. escaping `%`, `\` and `$`, although I don't use these characters right now) become a subset of LaTeX. Something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit.
```

I'm using Unicode characters for things like quotes and dashes (`“`, `”`, `–`, `—`, etc.) When I used LaTeX, this worked fine. But when I switched to XeLaTeX, it no longer puts spaces after the quotes. I wrote a script that manually converts all the characters to their equivalents (two backticks, `''`, `--`, `---`, etc.) which worked as a workaround.

For example, when I have the following code:

```
“It's a big problem,” he said.

``What's the problem,'' I asked.
```

It's rendered as:

> “It’s a big problem,”he said.
>
> “What’s the problem,” I asked.

My question is, is there a way to make XeLaTeX work properly without replacing all those characters?

The preamble of my `.tex` files follows (although it's merely temporary, as I'm still working on the content).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[serbian,english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Sazanami Mincho}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
```

Comment: I replaced the {quoting} tag with {punctuation}. Read [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) why.

Comment: You should not use `babel` with XeLaTeX. Did you mean to load [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia)?

Comment: A couple of comments about your code.  It's helpful to make a complete minimal example that compiles and shows your problem.  In this case, the minimal document needs only the `fontspec` package and the `xeCJK` package to show the problem, nothing else.  This shows that the problem is with the `xeCJK` package, which explicitly removes spacing after punctuation.  It's supposed to do this only with CJK characters.  Secondly, you shouldn't use `babel` with `xelatex`; you should use `polyglossia` instead. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/).

Comment: @Alan Munn: Yes, thank you, it was the `xeCJK` package, and yeah, I'll remember to provide a full example next time -- the problem is gone (or rather... different, I get bigger spaces) when I add `\setCJKmainfont{...}` which I added after adding the character replacement and I mistakenly included here. Shame on me. :)

Comment: A note for `xeCJK`: East Asian ideographs (CJK texts), don't use space between words at all. Thus `xeCJK` ignore all spaces between CJK symbols, to prevent extra spaces introduced by line wrapping. `xeCJK` also make it possilbe to break line after CJK ideographs, and imporves the spacing for the CJK punctuations. There are some ambiguous width characters used both in CJK text and western text, such as double quotes. — This is the problem you meet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the effect of `xeCJK`, it uses CJK fonts for these punctuations. If you don't need Japanese text (Sazanami Mincho is a Japanese font), you can delete it and `\setCJKmainfont` command. And if you use only a little, you can use `\makexeCJKinactive` to disable `xeCJK` for most western text of your document. I'm sorry that this command is not well documented in the English part of the manual. (I'm one of the developers of `xeCJK`.)

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Song Std}% a Chinese font
\begin{document}
\makexeCJKinactive

“Western text,” Okey.

\makexeCJKactive
“中文”（Chinese text）
\makexeCJKinactive

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, `babel` may not work well with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`. However, `polyglossia` package may conflict with `xeCJK`, even if you use `\makexeCJKinactive`, they both use the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to change the fonts for different glyphs. I didn't tested, thus I'm not quite sure about the compatibility.

If you use Japanese for only a few *words*, e.g. names of persons, you don't need `xeCJK`. You can just change the font manually for these words.

Comment: Actually I think the problem only arises if you *don't* set the CJKmainfont. If you do, the spacing actually works as advertised in the CJK manual (remove spacing only with CJK characters.) So I don't think you need to use the `\makexeCJKinactive` command to get things to work.

Comment: @Alan: If you don't set the CJK fonts, you actually don't need `xeCJK` at all. If you set the CJK main font, double quotes are typesetted in a different font, that's not required either.

Comment: I understand that; what I meant was that I could only replicate the problem by loading `xeCJK` and *not* setting the CJK main font. So removing *all* the `\makexeCJK(in)active` commands from your example still preserves the spaces in the English text.

Comment: What's more, closing double quote is a CJK post-punctuation in `xeCJK`. `xeCJK` also removes the space after CJK post-punctuations. That's because that CJK puctuations are full width in many CJK fonts, there's already enough spacing. This feature of CJK font hides the problem. However, there're also some CJK fonts (like Darth uses) with half-width punctuations, then the problem appears clearly.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the problem is partially font-dependent. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I know exactly what you mean. I will just jump right in and show you my macros solution:

```
> \glqq#SEL##INS#\grqq\,
```

The `\,` is just a "thin space" after the quotes to force a space after the quotation marks.

I use xelatex with babel all the time, works great darth vader. 
The following is in my heading:

```
%german package
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

Comment: This is an editor dependent solution (TeXShop?). And although you are correct that you can sometimes use `babel` with XeLaTeX, it depends on the language; see [Polyglossia, babel and xelatex](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.xetex/18416) but you should *never* use the `inputenc` package with XeLaTeX.