# No space after closing double quote

Tags: spacing, punctuation, languages, babel

As the title says, there's no spacing after my closing quotes, I have boiled my huge preamble down to the following,

```
% Manual: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Hello "I AM A" DUMMY SENTENCE
\end{document}
```

Which renders to

```
Hello "I AM A"DUMMY SENTENCE
```

And I would really like it to become

```
Hello "I AM A" DUMMY SENTENCE
```

I'm using the MikTex package for windows and my editor is TexMaker.

I looked at the [Spacing after closing double quotes in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12732/space-after-closing-double-quotes-in-xelatex) but I don't think the solution applies since I don't think I'm loading any CJK packages.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package turns `"` into an active character (so-called shorthands) that gives nice shortcuts for special treatment of non-English language. (Quick and dirty and typographically wrong work-around would be the use of `{}`<sup>[1](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-xspace),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/no-space-following-macro-without-argument)</sup>: `"I AM A"{} DUMMY`)

Correct danish quotation marks are acquired with `` "` ``  („) and `"'` (“).
By the way, since you use `utf8` anyway you could input `„` and `“` directly: `„I AM A“`

*Take a look at the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) manual and its section about the Danish language!*

You also might be interested in the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) that provides useful macros for quotation. It is also `babel`-aware and uses the right quotation marks.

### Code with `babel`'s shorthands

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Hello "`I AM A"' DUMMY SENTENCE
\end{document}
```

### Code with `\enquote` from the `csquotes` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Hello \enquote{I AM A} DUMMY SENTENCE
\end{document}
```

### Output of both variants

[image: Output of both variants]

### Stiff after `"`?

If you are still after the straight double quotation mark `"`, you can use `\textquotedbl`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Hello \textquotedbl I AM A\textquotedbl{} DUMMY SENTENCE 
\end{document}
```

#### Ouput with `\textquotedbl`

[image: \textquotedbl output]

Comment: This is absolutely excellent! thank you very much!

Comment: If it is necessary to use `"` for quotation marks, then you can use either changing the symbol category directly, using plain TeX `\catcode` (inside `document` environment), or using the command `\shorthandoff{"}` (also inside `document` environment) that is available in the [`babel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) documentation, as well as described in the documentation for [`babel-russian`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-russian), see section 3.1.

Answer (score 15):

Just to complement Qrrbrbirlbel's excellent answer, some comments about *why* this happens.

The `"` character should *never* be used in LaTeX to get quotes. The correct way to get (British style) double quotes is

```
``Opening and closing quotes''
```

The fact that `"` produces seemingly correct quotes (”) should not be relied upon: it can fail depending on the font one is using. Moreover, in good typography, opening and closing quotes should be different from each other.

When different typographic traditions are followed, the quotes change; German uses lowered opening quotes and raised closing ones, but reversed with respect to British usage. The same seems to hold for Danish, and `babel` provides shorthands for getting the correct characters without hunting for them on the keyboard, as explained by Qrrbrbirlbel.

In many language modules of `babel` the “straight double quote” character is used in the same way to introduce shorthands. These work in `babel` always in the same way:

```
<shorthand_char><char>
```

Some of these combinations are meaningful (they may mean different things in different languages), others don't. When the combination doesn't have a predefined meaning, `<shorthand_char>` fallbacks to something that, in the case of `"` is “print the character in the current font at position 34”. However the procedure for recognizing the following character uses `\@ifnextchar` which, by design, eats all the spaces that it finds in the process.

So in the example

```
Hello "I AM A" DUMMY SENTENCE
```

LaTeX looks whether the combination `"I` is meaningful for Danish, which isn't, so it prints

> ”I

Then it finds the second `"` and starts looking for the following character, swallowing spaces. Eventually `A` is found and since `"A` is not a predefined combination,

> ”A

is printed.

Comment: Before I read your great addition to the below answer, I was inclined to use `\usepackage[danish, english]{babel}` since that would make `"something"` be printed with spaces around the entire thing, and since I'm mostly writing in english (handins for school) it doesn't make sense to not have it loaded. But now I see that quotes does matter, and I'll practice the use of  ``Opening and closing quotes'' rather. Thanks for going in detail!

Comment: And to make the confusion complete: the `babel` manual—not exclusively I might add—uses the wrong characters in its manual: `"‘` for ``"` `` and `"’` for `"'` where `‘` and `’` are the (English) opening and closing single quotation marks produced by the auto-ligature feature of ` and `'` (similar to `` and `''`). … and then there are typewriter fonts that _don't_ use straight lines for `"` and `'` where you explicit want to distinguish `"` and `”`! `\end{rage}`

Comment: I just love how texexchange has code/uncode formatted your last message :) (I still understood it though^^)