# Can I write a document that is compilable with both latex and xetex?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I have just started to have a look at XeTeX and I am wondering whether to make the switch, however I am a bit scared... ...and I am basically wondering if I have to take the step fully or if I can have my document running on both engines somehow?

There seems to be some problems with utf8 encodings but can they be solved?

Comment: You want a [polyglot document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29)?

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use ifxetex to insert code meant only for one engine. Basically you will have to adapt inputenc (don't load it with xetex), font loading, perhaps language setup (babel/polyglossia), perhaps some driver options (but in general packages load the correct driver automatically).

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 %font commands
\else
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 %font packages
\fi
```

Comment: \ifxetex requires the ifxetex package, of course.

Comment: And there's `\ifluatex` all the same.

Comment: Maybe a little problem with the aux files, like .toc by example, if you use non ascii character.