# Including different content based on whether xelatex or pdflatex is invoked

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I write a document that is compilable with both latex and xetex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/can-i-write-a-document-that-is-compilable-with-both-latex-and-xetex)

I use XeLaTeX for my documents, and have a font set that I like. However, I also work with coauthors who aren't quite ready for xelatex yet, and use PDFLaTeX (or even plain LaTeX).

I'd like to construct a macro that includes certain content (fontspec and certain font packages) if I use XeLaTeX and other content if using PDFLaTeX/LaTeX. For example, something like

```
\if <*using xelatex*>
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<*my favorite font*>}
\else
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\fi
```

How would I set this up?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/detect-which-tex-engine-is-used

Comment: Thanks. I had a vague feeling I had seen the question before, but didn't search properly.