# How to switch between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX with some lines of commands in the preamble?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I write both English and Persian documents. I work with Texstudio and TeXLive. I have to compile Latin documents in pdfLatex and Persian documents in XeLatex. But I'd rather to change the configuration of LaTeX with some lines of code in the preamble of documents, instead of changing it every time and through the menus and manually.

Is there a command for switching between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTex?

Comment: There is an answer to your question, but I'm curious why you need pdfTeX specifically for your Latin documents, and cannot just always use XeTeX.

Comment: you can put comments in your preamble which may be understood by some editors to say which command to use but obviously you can not make this switch with any tex commands as you are asking which tex engine to use so you need to decide that before the document processing starts.

Comment: I'm calling in my editor (winedt) the engines with keyboard keys (e.g. ctrl+shift+p for pdflatex) and I'm rather confident that you could setup texstudio in a similar way. Beside this you could use a tool like arara.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have the feeling that pdfTeX is faster than XeTeX but it cannot handle Xepersian package which I'm using for writing in Persian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texstudio understands "magic comments", so you can specify the engine by using

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{...}
```

or

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{...}
```

If you then call "build & view" texstudio will process your file with the engine you specified in the magic comment.

Comment: Is there a generic solution that works in the compilation stage, and thus independent of the editor used?

Comment: @Marian This cannot work at compilation stage, how should the tex engine be chosen if the tex engine itself would be responsible for the choice? However you could use automation tools like arara: https://github.com/cereda/arara

Comment: Ah sorry I read the whole question wrong. What I wanted is something like `\ifxetex { ... } \ifpdftex{}`. I'll go on searching. Thanks for the quick reply and nevermind :)

Comment: @Marian Oh, there is a package for that - wait a sec

Comment: @Marian There are the `ifluatex` and `ifxetex` packages. With these packages you can check all major cases `\ifluatex
 code for luatex
\fi

\ifxetex
 code for xetex
\else
 remaining possibility contains pdflatex
\fi
`

Comment: Thanks. Just found it, too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/can-i-write-a-document-that-is-compilable-with-both-latex-and-xetex