# Error message when using biber

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

Great site here.  I have a question regarding Biblatex and Biber.  My current .tex file structure looks like this in TeXworks:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{inputenc} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib} 

\begin{document} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I run the Biber typeset, I get the following error:

```
INFO - This is biber 0.9.3
INFO - Logfile is 'myfile.blg'
FATAL - Cannot find control file 'myfile.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*(Edit by Richard 06/24/2011)

I applied the changes suggested below and although it worked for a single citation, when I include more than one, I get a PDF that only reads "Some text [A01]". Here is what I have now:

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lees:2011zi,
      author         = "Lees, J.P. and others",
      title          = "{Cross Sections for the Reactions $e^+e^- \to K^+ K^-
                    \pi^+\pi^-,\, K^+ K^- \pi^0\pi^0$, and $K^+ K^- K^+ K^-$
                    Measured Using Initial-State Radiation}",
      collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
      year           = "2011",
      note           = "* Temporary entry *",
      eprint         = "1103.3001",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}


@article{delAmoSanchez:2010fd,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Analysis of the $D^+ \to K^- \pi^+ e^+ \nu_e$ decay
                    channel}",
  collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D83",
  pages          = "072001",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.83.072001",
  year           = "2011",
  eprint         = "1012.1810",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}


@article{delAmoSanchez:2010yp,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Dalitz plot analysis of $D_s^+ \to K^+ K^- \pi^+$}",
  collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D83",
  pages          = "052001",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.83.052001",
  year           = "2011",
  eprint         = "1011.4190",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}


@article{delAmoSanchez:2010bx,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Search for the Decay $B^{0} \to \gamma \gamma$}",
  collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D83",
  pages          = "032006",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.83.032006",
  year           = "2011",
  eprint         = "1010.2229",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}


@article{delAmoSanchez:2010zd,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Measurement of the $B^0 \to \pi^\ell \ell^+ \nu$ and
                    $B^+ \to \eta^{(')} \ell^+ \nu$ Branching Fractions, the
                    $B^0 \to \pi^- \ell^+ \nu$ and $B^+ \to \eta \ell^+ \nu$
                    Form-Factor Shapes, and Determination of $|V_{ub}|$}",
  collaboration  = "BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D83",
  pages          = "052011",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.83.052011",
  year           = "2011",
  eprint         = "1010.0987",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}


@article{delAmoSanchez:2010bk,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Search for the Rare Decay $B \to K \nu \bar{nu}$}",
  collaboration  = "BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D82",
  pages          = "112002",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.82.112002",
  year           = "2010",
  eprint         = "1009.1529",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}

@article{delAmoSanchez:2010vq,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Observation of new resonances decaying to $D\pi$ and
                    $D^*\pi$ in inclusive $e^+e^-$ collisions near
                    $\sqrt{s}=$10.58 GeV}",
  collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D82",
  pages          = "111101",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.82.111101",
  year           = "2010",
  eprint         = "1009.2076",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}
 \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____(EDIT BY RICHARD 06/27/2011)

When I compile this, I get almost perfect results, however there seems to be several "¿" throughout the document. Also, [hep-ex] is always displayed after each citation (I guess it prints the primaryClass at the end). Can I somehow disable the [hep-ex] from showing?

Also, would it be worth it to run XeTeX instead of latex when I compile?  I'm looking for the best way to get unicode characters (preserve sub/superscripts, etc).  Should I add the line, \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} if I do this?

Thanks for all your help.

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@Article{Aubert:2007sea,
     author    = "Aubert, Bernard and others",
     collaboration = "BABAR",
     title     = "{Evidence for b ---> d gamma Transitions From a Sum of
              Exclusive Final States in the Hadronic Final State Mass
              Range 1.0-GeV/c**2 < M(X(d)) < 1.8-GeV/c**2}",
     year      = "2007",
     eprint    = "0708.1652",
     archivePrefix = "arXiv",
     primaryClass  =  "hep-ex",
     SLACcitation  = "%%CITATION = 0708.1652;%%"
}

@Article{:2010ip,
     author    = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
     collaboration = "BABAR",
     title     = "{Dalitz-plot Analysis of B0 --> D0bar pi+ pi-}",
     journal   = "PoS",
     volume    = "ICHEP2010",
     year      = "2010",
     pages     = "250",
     eprint    = "1007.4464",
     archivePrefix = "arXiv",
     primaryClass  =  "hep-ex",
     SLACcitation  = "%%CITATION = 1007.4464;%%"
}


@Article{delAmoSanchez:2010rq,
    author    = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
    collaboration = "BABAR",
    title     = "{Evidence for direct CP violation in the measurement of the
              Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa angle gamma with B-+ --> D(*)
              K(*)-+ decays}",
    journal   = "Phys. Rev. Lett.",
    volume    = "105",
    year      = "2010",
    pages     = "121801",
    eprint    = "1005.1096",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass  =  "hep-ex",
    doi       = "10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.121801",
    SLACcitation  = "%%CITATION = 1005.1096;%%"
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: a) Make sure you run latex first b) Cite at least one works included in your `.bib` file (or add `\nocite{*}` somewhere in your document). Does the error persist?

Comment: When you say "run latex", do you mean to type "latex myfile" in terminal? If so, I got the following message: ! Undefined control sequence.
    <recently read> \addbibresource 
                                
    l.5 \addbibresource
                   {mybib.bib}

Comment: I also included the \nocite{*} right after "\begin{document} "

Comment: `\addbibresource` was introduced in biblatex 1.2, so you need to update your TeX installation. biber 0.9.3 only works with biblatex 1.5.

Comment: I updated everything on TeX Live and still getting the same error.  Do I have to update something manually?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a rather minimal, but compilable test example. Does this example (saved, say, as `biblatextest.tex`) compile for you without errors? If not, what does the logfile (`biblatextest.txt`), especially the section `*File List`, say?

EDIT: The proper compile sequence for the example (if one doesn't use a makefile like [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/)) is

```
-pdflatex biblatextest
-biber biblatextest
-pdflatex biblatextest
```

Note the use of `biber` as a replacement for `bibtex`!

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

EDIT 2: In response to the updated question: In the code snippet `\autocite{A01}`, `A01` is the citekey of the first (and only) bibentry in my `.bib` file (it starts with `@misc{A01,` `misc` being the BibTeX type). What do you expect when you cite an entry that isn't included in your `.bib` file?

EDIT 3: That's a new question, isn't it? ;-) To remove `[hep-ex]` from every bibliography entry, add the following to your preamble:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{eprintclass}}
```

And yes, XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX may be worth a try. For details see [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex).

Comment: I tried this using the Biber typset in TexXworks and it gave the same error.  I opened terminal and typed -latex biblatextest -bibtex biblatextest -latex biblatextest  -latex biblatextest and I got a PDF that read, "Some text [A01]."

Comment: I don't know a "Biber" typeset in TeXworks, only a "BibTeX" one. Try "LaTeXmk" instead. (And when compiling from the terminal, use `-biber biblatextest` instead of `-bibtex biblatextest`!)

Comment: Now that works! I compiled in terminal with biber and the process worked great. Now in the PDF that I created, the characters are now in UTF-8? I changed the title to one that reads: Searches for the baryon- and lepton-number violating decays $B\rightarrow{}\Lambda{}c+l-$, $B-\rightarrow{}\Lambda{}l-$, and $B-\rightarrow{}\Lambda{}\ifmmode\bar\else\textasciimacron\fi{}l-$  I compiled and the PDF view was 100% accurate. So with Biber, those characters are converted to UTF-8?

Comment: Indeed -- `biber` is able to decode LaTeX character macros into UTF-8. See section 2.5 of the biber documentation for details.

Comment: @lockstep: Please note the pending edit by Richard.

Comment: @Richard: You might want to update your question instead of editing the answer.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Question updated.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks for your answer.  Is there a way to process all the BibTeX using a single line of code?  OR do I have to add \autocite{citekey} for every bibentry?

Comment: You mean without citing the entries? Add `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: @lockstep I apologize for all the new questions.  Would you mind drawing up a skeleton for XeLaTeX?  I'm not sure how to specify the packages from the link.  Thanks.

Comment: @Richard: I don't use XeLaTeX, but I suggest to a) remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` from your example b) compile it with `xelatex` -- `biber` -- `xelatex`.

Comment: @Richard: One more thing: As you have accepted my answer, please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting it).

Comment: @lockstep: I added the upvote to your answer.  Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: @lockstep: One last question, I promise!  How would I ad multiple "clearfields", so doi, eprint #, hep-ex and archivePrefix would all be hidden?  Would it be something like this?  \AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{eprintclass}%
  \clearfield{archivePrefix}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
}

Comment: There are package options like `doi=false`. See section 3.1.2.2 of the manual for details.

Comment: @lockstep: So something like \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}{doi=false}   ?

Comment: @lockstep: NVM, used \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false, eprint=false} ... Thanks for all your help -- I appreciate it!

Answer (score 8):

I have seen the same message when typesetting a tex file when using TeXShop.

> Cannot find control file something.bcf did you pass the
>   "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

The message occurs when the tex file or other configuration files specify one BibTeX engine while TeXShop specifies another.

For example if the Engine settings in TeXShop prefs specify 'biber' rather than 'bibtex' while the tex file includes...

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

Conversely another tex file might use a class file to manage styles (.cls), specifying biber like so...

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

In order to typeset from within TexShop, your prefs need to be changed to achieve agreement between the typesetting environment and the parameter in your file, e.g.: **biber** rather than bibtex, or **bibtex** rather than biber.

The problem does not occur when compiling from the command line using the desired BibTex engine.