# How to use the MS Trebuchet font?

Tags: fonts

My thesis may use Times New Roman or MS Trebuchet font. I have written it using Times, but now I'd like a look at how it appears in MS Trebuchet. Currently I just use the `times` package, which I guess sets the Times New Roman font as active. How can I try MS Trebuchet? I briefly tried xetex, but it had a problem even with the document type: `report`; I also use graphics etc.

I use both Cygwin and Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: related/similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/calibri-in-protext

Comment: Don’t use the `times` package for setting Times as your font. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/setting-font-family-for-the-whole-document/33678#33678 for the recommended package to use. Also, I’d like to echo the comment that Trebuchet isn’t very suitable as a thesis typeface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trebuchet is a sans serif font,. I have some doubt that is suitable for the main text. On windows you can use the font together with the `winfonts` package available on CTAN, it works only with pdflatex (not latex). But it doesn't contain the fonts themselves, so you should at first check if you have `trebuc.ttf`.

An example document is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pdfmapfile{+winfonts.map}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{trebuchet}
\begin{document}
abc \textit{abc} \bfseries abc  \textit{abc}
\end{document}
```