# Use Trebuchet font

Tags: fonts

How can I use the `MS Trebuchet` font in `LaTeX`, or in this case, `tikzposter`? I have tried the awnser from [How to use the MS Trebuchet font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33739/how-to-use-the-ms-trebuchet-font) with this code:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33739/how-to-use-the-ms-trebuchet-font
\pdfmapfile{+winfonts.map}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{trebuchet}
```

But I just get a warning like this:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/trebuchet/m/n' undefined
```

The formatting does then not work with bold or italic text anymore.

Comment: It seems to be a general problem.

Comment: I am sure it exists on my computor since I can use it with R.

Comment: I think it's the same issue as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339253/82917. The question you linked is from 2011, Windows font support broke around 2018.

Comment: Just use LuaLaTeX and use Trebuchet like any other .ttf font.

Comment: @Ingmar how do I do that?

Comment: While waiting for @Ingmar to post as an answer... Add `\usepackage{fontspec}` just below document class. Then add `\setmainfont{MS Trebuchet}` just below that. Do not use `fontenc` or `rmdefault` (already invoked by fontspec). Not sure about the pdfmapfile, but I think it should be omitted. Then compile with lualatex. Command line `lualatex yourdocument.tex` so that you are compiling with utf8 encoding (known as TU within TeX).

Comment: @rallg Definitely drop the map file addition. OP: also, if you are loading `inputenc`, drop that, too, and drop `textcomp`, if you use that. If you're using other font packages, drop if not compatible. You can keep maths fonts traditional and just change the text fonts to `fontspec`, which is probably the path of least resistance.

Comment: I did that, but I still get the error `Font shape `T1/aer/b/sc' undefined` and the font does not change.

edit: now it says: `! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX.(fontspec)(fontspec) You must change your typesetting engine to,(fontspec) e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of(fontspec) "latex" or "pdflatex".Type <return> to continue.... \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}`

Comment: And yes, I selected LuaTeX in Texmaker

Comment: Select `lualatex` not `luatex`. If your system does not have `lualatex` (it is probably a softlink to `luahbtex`) then create the softlink yourself.

Comment: Ok, that did not work either. How do I create the softlink? Sorry for questions, but I am new to this

Comment: Are you using Windows? You did not say. If so, I will defer to others, regarding softlink (if needed there). Meanwhile: Consider using font `Fira Sans` instead of Trebuchet. It is available as a TeX package, and includes a file format that does not reuire `fontspec` or `lualatex`. Instructions are in the LaTeX font catalog, at this page: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/firasans/

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using Windows. Unfortunately, I cannot use anything else than trebuchet since it is a part of a theme I must follow imposed by my employer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note it's **Trebuchet MS** not **MS Trebuchet**. then, with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Trebuchet MS}

\begin{document}

One two \textbf{three} \textit{four}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, good catch! Possibly the OP is also having trouble launching `lualatex` from the GUI?

Comment: @rallg what's a GUI?:-) I launch lualatex by typing lualatex on the commandline...

Comment: If I put a cheeseburger in the microwave for too long, then the cheese becomes very GUI. I also use command line (Linux).

Comment: I manged to use the commandline, thanks for suggesting that. However, the font does not change as far as I can tell. I get the error `LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

edit: It was a typo by me. Problem solved. Thanks a lot for the help!