# Use "non-standard" font in Latex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I downloaded the font "Antonio" from Google and added it to the font setting (Windows 11). I know it could be possible to change the font using XeLateX, but I would like to do without xelatex. Do you know how to do it in a simpler way?

Comment: use lualatex or xelatex, there are tools to make subset fonts for pdflatex but it is much much much harder. see this answer on using a system font with lualatex, it just takes one line, and if you replace the font name by **Antonio** then that will work for your font.

Comment: You can use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (preferred, these days), but not (without a lot of useless hassle) pdfLaTeX. But using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is fundamentally no different from using pdfLaTeX except in some corner cases.

Comment: @Teepeemm I only posted it a minute before, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699709/1090

Comment: As @AlanMunn noted, LuaLaTeX is preferred, these days. Either way, you will be using utf-8 technology, with an OpenType or TrueType font, for the least hassle.