# Bug in swedish-babel?

Tags: babel

When I use the Swedish babel package, the header on the even sides of the table of contents  is written "INNEHåLL" (note the lower-case å which should be an Å). If I use the English version, it correctly says CONTENTS. Is this a bug?

I don't have a minimal example for this as it requires at least a page worth of chapters for the contents but here is a screenshot:[image]

**Edit:** If I use the book class I can get an empty page with this behavior. I managed to strip down all packages I'm using and it appears that the issue is caused by the fontspec package:

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

**Edit 2:** I changed now to polyglossia. Here is my current preamble. The commented packages are probably the ones giving me trouble:

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{a4paper}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont{PT Sans}
\setmonofont[AutoFakeBold=1.4, AutoFakeSlant=0.2]{Inconsolata}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{{ill/}}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
```

**Edit 3** My solution so far was the following (can't self-answer yet):

1) Changed `babel` to `polyglossia`.

2) Deleted `fontspec` (included by `polyglossia`) and `amssymb` (incompatible with `polyglossia`).

3) Changed `listingsutf8` to `listings` and now using `unicode-math`

Comment: Really wild guess: I noticed you're not using CM or LM as a font, but I have no clue which font this is. Perhaps your font doesn't have an capital Å (either not at all or just not in slanted/italic).

Comment: @doncherry: The font is PT Sans. It does have Å as normal text displays fine.

Comment: Use `polyglossia` instead of `babel` when compiling with `xelatex`. Also see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex) question.

Comment: If I use polyglossia I get the following error: `Command \Finv already defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it, with a combination of help from answers and comments:

1) Changed `babel` to `polyglossia`.

2) Deleted `font-spec` and moved `amssymb` to the top (as it was incompatible with `polyglossia`).

Answer (score 11):

Check if you use `\uppercase` somewhere and replace it by `\MakeUppercase`. This is a usual weakness of `\uppercase`, it doesn't show effect on macros in its argument. Compare:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\uppercase{Inneh\aa ll}

\MakeUppercase{Inneh\aa ll}
\end{document}
```

[image: MakeUppercase example]

That's not a bug in babel. It can be a weakness in your code, as above, in a package or in the way you are using a package for the headers.

It works as expected for example with the default `headings` pages style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\section{test}
...
% repeat chapters and sections many times to get a TOC longer than a page
\end{document}
```

[image: headings example]

It works also if you use `fancyhdr` and `fancy` page style:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I localized the issue - see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

You original problem with babel can be solved like this:

```
\addto\captionsswedish{%
\def\contentsname{Innehåll}}
```

Regarding your current example:

1. Don't use listingsut8 with xelatex. Use listings
2. Do you really need amssymb? (It's the source of the `Command \Finv already defined`). If yes you must load it before `fontspec` (so before `polyglossia` as it loads `fontspec`), but be aware that some of its definitions will be overwritten.

Comment: I don't think I need amssymb, so I have removed it now and replaced with unicode-math. Also, it looks like I could get rid of fontspec as well.

Comment: "get rid of" is a bit harsh. You should use it, but both polyglossia and unicode-math already load it, so you don't have to do it yourself (but it doesn't do much harm if you do it anyway).

Comment: I see. I'm fairly new to xelatex and I don't have too much experience with latex in general, so I guess I have a lot of studying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how `babel` modifies the contents, but how about trying the following:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inneh\aa ll}
```

Your `\chaptermark` should use `\MakeUppercase` to modify this and make it UPPERCASE in the header.