# XeTeX: "ß" compiles as "SS", German umlauts work

Tags: xetex, fontspec, characters, font-encodings

I have a problem with XeLaTeX. Although German umlauts (äöü) work, "ß" compiles to "SS".

I use TeX Live 2011 on Debian x64.

See this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[naustrian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Das "`s"' in "`daß"' muß (Achtung, "`muss"' schreibt man normal so) einsam bleiben,
könntest Du auch "`welches"' schreiben.
\end{document}
```

compiles to

> Das „s“ in „daSS“ muSS (Achtung, „muss“ schreibt man normal so) einsam
>   bleiben, könntest Du auch „welches“ schreiben.

(You might think the problem is related to `babel`, but I tried it without `babel` as well - `babel` just makes the quotation marks work right but doesn't harm the "ß").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With XeLaTeX, use the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package instead of [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc). For details, see [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex).

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document}
Das "`s"' in "`daß"' muß (Achtung, "`muss"' schreibt man normal so) einsam bleiben,
könntest Du auch "`welches"' schreiben.
\end{document}
```

Comment: **babel** can actually be used, at least for German and Austrian German, although **polyglossia** is probably better.

Comment: @egreg: Normally, I don't use XeLaTeX, so I wanted to stick to Phillip's advice (in the "reference" Q+A).

Comment: It's *very* important also to save the files in UTF-8 encoding! But from Marcel's output it seems that encoding was actually used.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Maybe I'm to stupid, but now I get the error message "! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu1enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding."

Comment: @Marcel: (Assuming your comment is not about Mico's answer) Try to delete all auxiliary files and then compile again.

Comment: Thank you! No, my comment is a result of copying your code to my editor. Sorry, deleting the auxilary files didn't solve it.

Comment: @Marcel: Sorry -- it works for me, and I'm not a XeLaTeX expert, so I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: finally got it - I think it was a problem with file access rights with some of the files in my texlive installation. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think the real problem in your MWE is that you're using the `T1` font encoding, whereas one should use `EU1` for xe(la)tex -- and `EU2` for lua(la)tex. If you change this parameter to `EU1`, the `\ss` instances in your MWE will compile just fine: if `EU1` is specified, xetex will automatically load the "latin modern" fonts for you. If you're OK with this font choice, you needn't load the `fontspec` package explicitly.

An entirely separate issue: you still need to load either `babel` or, better yet, `polyglossia` in order to obtain language-appropriate forms of the quotation marks.

Comment: thank you - should work, but I get the same error message as i just posted (! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu1enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.)

Comment: Which version of the `Latin Modern` fonts and of the `fontspec` package, are you using? `fontspec 2.2` was released just a few days ago; it contains a lot of improvements relative to version 2.1. Page 55 of the `fontspec` manual has the reference to the EU1 and EU2 encoding schemes and notes that "Now that XETEX can find fonts in the texmf tree, the Latin Modern OpenType fonts can be used as the defaults." I suppose this means that if you don't have the Opentype version of the latin modern fonts, you'll need to to the `\usepackage{fontspec}` route detailed in the answer by @lockstep.