# mathdesign compiles ß to SS

Tags: xetex, mathdesign, german, extended-characters

I'd like to use the package `mathdesign`, but it somehow makes problems with the german letter `ß`. My question is related to [XeTeX: “ß” compiles as “SS”, German umlauts work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/xetex-ss-compiles-as-ss-german-umlauts-work) but different because the reason seems to be `mathdesign` here.
The effect is best show with the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}%
%\usepackage{utopia}\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
The german ß compiles to SS when used with \emph{mathdesign} package.
\end{document}
```

beeing compiled with line 4 uncommented resulting in *[image: desired result]* or with line 4 activated resulting in *[image: unwanted]*.
Ä, Ö, Ü and so on works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old thread, but things have changed in the last ten years.

#### With `mathdesign`

You need to replace the text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont{erewhon}

\begin{document}

The German ß comes up right when used with \texttt{mathdesign} package.
\[
a+b=c-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### With `fourier`

You still need to change the text font.

[image]

#### With `fourier-otf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document}

The German ß comes up right when used with \texttt{fourier-otf} package.
\[
a+b=c-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Unless you *really* have to use `polyglossia,` you can try the following, which seems to work fine on my machine:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Utopia}
\begin{document}
The german ß compiles to ß when used with \emph{mathdesign} package.
\begin{equation}
  a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses the OpenType version of Utopia (for text), available [here,](http://ghostscript.com/~tor/stuff/fonts/utopia/) which I think is a bit more appropriate in XeTeX/LuaTeX. For math, `mathdesign` remains in use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example. But - is polyglossia buggy? I startedt using XeLaTeX about 18 months ago and red somewhere, that like babel in LaTeX, polyglossia !SHOULD! be used in XeLaTeX. What is the truth? Thanks.

Comment: @BastianEbeling here is a little bit of insight: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel

Comment: I've been following Ulrike Fischer's advice to just stick with babel (in Xe/LuaLaTeX) until you run into problems ...which so far I haven't; the scripts I've used it with have been working fine (Latin, Cyrillic, polytonic Greek).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Charter rather than Utopia as your font, then you can also use `xcharter` instead of `mathdesign`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcharter-otf}
\begin{document}
Straße, STRAẞE, {\scshape Straße}, $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [the `xcharter` pkg on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcharter) for more info.

Comment: The OP wanted Utopia, not Charter.

Comment: I am, of course, aware of that. But the issue being asked about is not specific to the font used; and in any case after over a decade, anyone visiting this question, facing the same problem, can fairly be assumed to not be the OP.