# Cannot get small caps acronyms to work using glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, bold, small-caps

I've managed to get `glossaries` to set the acronyms in the body in small caps in the way I want, but in the list of acronyms they insist on coming out in lower-case.

Can anyone (a) tell me what I've missed and (b) prune the irrelevant (as I'm basically poking around without really understanding the bowels)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,
    style=list,
    nonumberlist,
    shortcuts,
    smallcaps,
]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
    description={\the\glslongtok},%
    name={\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}},%
    symbol={\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}},%
    }
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\SetCustomStyle
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{xts}{Tsp}{Tomato Soup Protocol}
\newacronym{xfc}{Fcp}{Fried Cheese Protocol}
\begin{document}

We like \acs{xts} and \acs{xfc}.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Body:

[image: We like...]

List:

[image: Acronyms...]

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks for the tag edit. One day, I'm sure, I'll get them right at the first attempt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) package with the `T1` option to obtain bold small caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,
    style=list,
    nonumberlist,
    shortcuts,
    smallcaps,
]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
    description={\the\glslongtok},%
    name={\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}},%
    symbol={\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}},%
    }
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\SetCustomStyle
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{xts}{Tsp}{Tomato Soup Protocol}
\newacronym{xfc}{Fcp}{Fried Cheese Protocol}
\begin{document}

We like \acs{xts} and \acs{xfc}.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Works nicely, thanks. Should I expect problems using utf-8 files with Xe/LuaLatex? (I've tried it thus, and it works, but is it _correct_? Plus, should I load fontspec before or after fontenc?)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex

Comment: No problem. The other question seems to suggest I *not* use `fontenc` with utf-8/fontspec. My non-MWE fails with just fontspec, but the MWE is OK. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: What if I use `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` to have `\textsi{small italic caps}`, can I use bold caps as well?

Answer (score 5):

If you want non bold small caps, write this after loading `glossaries`

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theglossary}{\begin{description}[font=\normalfont]}
```

This works because the `theglossary` environment is actually `description`.