# Hyperlinking a drawing

Tags: xetex, hyperref

Is it possible to hyperlink a drawn line to a specific page in the document? I use following command to draw a line: `\line(1,0){20}` Many thanks! Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={0.2in,0.2in},vmargin={0in,0in},
paperwidth=3.56in, paperheight=5.95in}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\phantomsection \label{PP1}
First page \newpage

\phantomsection \label{PP2}
Second page \newpage

\centering
\line(1,0){20}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Toc might be little complicated. Suppose I labeled a specific page as PP1, now I need a drawn line linked to this page. How do I do it?

Comment: I added MWE. Please ignore TOC. How do you link a drawn line to a page labeled as PP1?

Comment: @ Marco, I understand the work around. However, that doesn't solve my problem, because now the hyperlinked area becomes the size of a font, and placed under a line. I need that line hyperlinked only.

Comment: I found the problem, but no solution ;-). It's XeLaTeX related. With PDFLaTeX and `\hyperlink{PP1}{\hbox{\line(1,0){50}}}` it works well.

Comment: See: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2005-October/002480.html

Comment: With PDFLaTeX even `\hyperref[PP1]{\line(1,0){1}}` command works. But I have to use XeLaTeX instead. So, the problem is how do I make this command work on XeLaTeX?

Comment: Hey Marco, is it possible to implement this solution in our problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54077/14830 if so how? :)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel See Nina's comment.

Answer (score 6):

Vairis has shown in his answer, that XeTeX has some problems, if the link does not
contain character glyphs. LaTeX's `picture` environment uses glyphs of a special font
for `\line`, `\vector` and `\circle`. This is also the reason for the limitations
(only some angles, the sizes are restricted, …). Horizontal and vertical lines
are the exception, because they are drawn by rules.

- Detected by XeTeX: character glyphs.
- Not detected by XeTeX: rules, images, boxes without glyphs, ...

As solution I have now implemented `\XeTeXLinkBox` in `hyperref` 2012/08/18 v6.83b, from
`README`:

> ### \XeTeXLinkBox
>
> When XeTeX generates a link annotation, it does not look   at the boxes (as the other drivers), but only at the character 
>   glyphs. If there are no glyphs (images, rules, …), then   it does
>   not generate a link annotation. Macro `\XeTeXLinkBox`   puts its
>   argument in a box and adds spaces at the lower left   and upper right
>   corners. An additional margin can be specified   by setting it to the
>   dimen register `\XeTeXLinkMargin`. The default   is `2pt`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> % xelatex
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{1pt}
> \begin{document}
> \section{Hello World}
> \newpage
> \label{sec:hello}
> \hyperref[sec:hello]{%
>   \XeTeXLinkBox{\rule{10mm}{10mm}}%
> }
> \end{document}
> ```

Modified example from Vairis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{hyperref}{2012/08/18}{%
}{%
  \newdimen\XeTeXLinkMargin
  \newsavebox\XeTeXLink@box
  % Space is taken from Zapf Dingbats with zero height and depth
  \font\XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 1sp\relax
  \newcommand*{\XeTeXLink@space}{%
    \begingroup\XeTeXLink@font\@xxxii\endgroup
  }
  \newcommand{\XeTeXLinkBox}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \leavevmode
      \sbox0{#1}%
      \begingroup
        \dimen0=\dp0 %
        \advance\dimen0 by \XeTeXLinkMargin
        \setbox2=\llap{%
          \hbox to \XeTeXLinkMargin{%
            \lower\dimen0\hbox{\XeTeXLink@space}%
            \hss
          }%
        }%
        \dp2=\dp0 %
        \ht2=\ht0 %
        \copy2 %
      \endgroup
      \copy0 %
      \dimen0=\ht0 %
      \advance\dimen0 by \XeTeXLinkMargin
      \setbox2=\rlap{%
        \hbox to \XeTeXLinkMargin{%
          \hss
          \raise\dimen0\hbox{\XeTeXLink@space}%
        }%
      }%
      \dp2=\dp0 %
      \ht2=\ht0 %
      \copy2 %
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\phantomsection \label{PP1}
First page \newpage

\phantomsection \label{PP2}
Second page \newpage

\centering

\hyperref[PP1]{\line(1,1){10}}
\qquad
\hyperref[PP1]{\vector(1,0){10}}
\qquad
\hyperref[PP2]{%
  \XeTeXLinkBox{%
    \begin{picture}(10,10)%
      \put(5,10){\line(0,-1){10}}%
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}   
\qquad
\hyperref[PP2]{%
  \begin{picture}(10,10)%
    \put(5,10){\XeTeXLinkBox{\line(0,-1){10}}}%
  \end{picture}%
}
\qquad
\hyperref[PP1]{\XeTeXLinkBox{\line(1,0){10}}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: Links with picture objects in XeTeX]

The reason for using the space from Zapf Dingbats are:

- There is a space glyph.
- Package `pifont` is already loaded, therefore the fonts are very likely installed.
- The height and depth of the space glyph is zero.
- The width is minimized by loading the font at the size of `1sp`.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to make your link in different ways:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={0.2in,0.2in},vmargin={0in,0in},
paperwidth=3.56in, paperheight=5.95in}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\phantomsection \label{PP1}

First page \newpage

\phantomsection \label{PP2}
Second page \newpage

\centering
\hyperref[PP1]{\line(1,1){10}} %works

\hyperref[PP1]{\vector(1,0){10}} %works

\hyperref[PP1]{\dotfill} %works

\hyperref[PP2]{\begin{picture}(10,10)\put(0,-1){\line(0,-1){10}} \end{picture}} %not working

\hyperlink{PP1}{\hbox{\line(1,0){10}}} %not working

\end{document}
```

Got the following output :
[image: Different links]

With XeLaTeX first three links worked, but the last two did not. (pdfLaTeX does not have this issue)

What I can get out from this is that XeLaTeX does not want to make plain horizontal/vertical line as a link. Maybe because completely horizontal/vertical line is being drawn differently.
If you use any real graphical object (for example angled line or vector), then it can easily be used as a link.
Hope this will help you to find some kind of a workaround.