# Xelatex hyperref problem

Tags: xetex, hyperref, polyglossia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlinking a drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56802/hyperlinking-a-drawing)

I need a drawn line hyperlinked a specific page in the document. In the following MWE when I comment out polyglossia package and use PDFLatex, it works fine. However, if I use polyglossia package with XeLaTex it doesn't. For my document I have to use Polyglossia/XeLaTeX. Need your help. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={0.2in,0.2in},vmargin={0in,0in},
paperwidth=3.56in, paperheight=5.95in}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\phantomsection\label{PP1}
First page. \newpage

\phantomsection\label{PP2}
Second page. \newpage

\hyperref[PP1]{\line(1,0){200}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: PLease edit your original question to include the additional information instead of asking a new (and as far as I can see, near identical) one.

Comment: In the original question a problem was found which lead to a different question. Now, the question is about hyperref not functioning well on Xelatex.

Comment: That's true, but you should only ask a new question if the first one has received an acceptable answer. In your case, it has only received a (quite useful) hint what the actual *problem* is.

Comment: Now I need your super brain to solve my problem, please.

Comment: XeLaTeX and `hyperref` are not among my super powers. :-) BTW, I upvoted your original question.

Comment: My Texmaker is configured to `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. How do I incorporate `pdflatex` into this command to have texmaker compile the document with xelatex and pdflatex together?

Comment: Sorry -- you have to choose between xelatex and pdflatex.

Comment: That's fine, but can't I somehow tell my compiler whenever you see `\hyperref[PP1]{\line(1,0){200}}` treat it as `PDFLatex` ? Isn't `ifPDFlatex` for this purpose?

Comment: I'm afraid no. pflatex and xelatex are compilation methods for whole documents, not in-document switches.

Comment: Then please include Xelatex and hyperref into your super power field and get me a solution. lol