# Can PDF search find words with ligatures in XeLaTeX-documents?

Tags: xetex, pdf, ligatures, copy-paste

Is there some way allow PDF search to find words with ligatures?  I use XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
Prefix.
\end{document}
```

In the resulting pdf file, searching for the word "Prefix" fails.

Comment: Note that this is searchable e.g. with SumatraPDF on Win7. I'm assuming you used Acrobat Reader, with which I can reproduce your problem. Good MWE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{fontspec}`. This actually [loads the package `fontenc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex#comment49954_3000), which would solve your problem for pdfLaTeX.

As a result, the ec fonts are loaded instead of the standard Computer Modern fonts, as Ulrike remarked in the comments. For other fonts, other solutions might apply; this answer addresses a standard setup as seen in the OP's MWE.

Comment: Your solution works because with `fontspec` you are using a different font which uses correct glyph names and so allow the pdf reader to "understand" the ligature. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (which switches from the cm fonts to the ec fonts), `\usepackage{lmodern}` or `\usepackage{times}` work too.

Comment: @Ulrike - Thanks for your clue in this comment!  fontspec doesn't help for fonts without proper glyph names, e.g. Cambria.  I switched to LibertineOTF and all is well.

Comment: I have a similar problem. After adding '\usepackage{fontspec}' to the minimal example the word "prefix" becames searchable, however after adding '\setmainfont[Path=Fonts/,Extension=.ttf,BoldFont=FrutigerLTCom-Bold,ItalicFont=FrutigerLTCom-Italic,BoldItalicFont=FrutigerLTCom-BoldItalic]{FrutigerLTCom-Light}' the problem returns.

Comment: By the way, the document with the Frutiger font worked for years until I shortly updated my MikTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, could you look at this?

Comment: @Mik don't add a new question in a comment. Create a new question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ok, will do so

Comment: Here is the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430054/failing-search-for-words-with-ligatures-after-update