# Failing search for words with ligatures after update

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec, ligatures

After updating my MikTeX distribution couple of days ago I discovered that search for words with ligatures (such as "fi" in prefix), which has worked before, fails.

Here the MWE illustrating the problem (compilation with xelatex):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=Fonts/,
             Extension=.ttf,
             BoldFont=FrutigerLTCom-Bold,
             ItalicFont=FrutigerLTCom-Italic,
             BoldItalicFont=FrutigerLTCom-BoldItalic]%
            {FrutigerLTCom-Light}
\begin{document}
Prefix.
\end{document}
```

As discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67848/can-pdf-search-find-words-with-ligatures-in-xelatex-documents), the line `\usepackage{fontspec}` enables the correct behaviour.

Adding the font settings `\setmainfont[...]{FutigerLTCom-Light}` leads to the incorrect behaviour. Is there a bug that possibly has been introduced to the fontspec package or somewhere else in one of the latest MikTeX updates?

Comment: I can confirm that there is problem, not only in miktex but also in texlive 2018. It looks like a xdvipdfmx problem and I did sent a message to the texlive list.

Comment: The problem has been hopefully fixed in the sources. I can't say when it will picked up by miktex.

Comment: I updated my MikTeX distribution, but unfortunately I see no changes. BTW, if I use `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, everything works as expected...

Comment: I have miktex next here on the PC, perhaps the newest xdvipdfmx isn't yet in the standard miktex.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, after the latest update everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved after updating as mentioned in comments.