# ffi ligature in Libertinus italic

Tags: fonts, fontspec, ligatures, libertinus

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
    Affine finance

    \itshape Affine finance
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is no `ffi` ligature applied in the italic text?

Inspecting `libertinusserif-italic.otf` with FontForge I see that it actually has a `ffi` ligature in the same block as the `fi` ligature:

[image]

I compiled with LuaLaTeX from TeXLive2018. I updated to TL2018 yesterday and deleted the old distribution, so I can't try with an older version, but if I remember correctly, I already observed this behaviour in TL2017.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with LuaLaTeX (1.07.0, MikTeX on Win 10). With XeLaTeX (0.99999, ditto) it is even worse: I don't even get the italic 'ff' ligature there in 'ffi'. The stand-alone 'ff' ligature works fine everywhere. But the italic 'fi' ligature fails with XeLaTeX, while LuaLaTeX is fine with it. (Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430054/35864)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a font bug.  The glyphs are there but they are unmapped.  Reported here: https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/issues/174

Screenshots from Font Forge.

[image]

[image]

There are a few oddities though.  How does LuaTeX find the `f_i` ligature even though it is unmapped?  Why can't XeTeX at least resolve the `f_f` ligature?  I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

With lualatex you can use mode=base:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Renderer=Basic]

\begin{document}
    Affine finance

    \itshape Affine finance ff ffl

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the `Renderer` feature? I've looked into the `fontspec` manual, but I did not really find any description of this. What does it mean and why does it changes something like ligatures? I've also read your comment https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/174, where you change the `mode` to `base` or `node`. Again, what do these mean? It seems to me they are related to `Renderer`.