# Passing normal title to the pdf bookmark

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, pdftex

I am writing a document and a section as a very long title troubling my header. To work around this, I am using the short title like this:

```
\section[bla]{blablabla}
```

This works fine for the header, but the pdf bookmark is now using the short title instead of the normal title. Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is the definition of the hyperref package:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
bookmarksopen=true,
pdftitle={Title},
pdfauthor={Author},
pdfsubject={Blablabla},
pdfkeywords={},
pdfmenubar=true,
pdfhighlight=/O,
pdfpagemode=None,
pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,
pdffitwindow=true,
bookmarksopen=true,
hidelinks=true}
```

Comment: Following the advice of other, more experienced users, [you should avoid specifying driver names (e.g., `pdftex`, `xetex`) excplicitly when loading packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2985/14497). For one, this makes your life easier when you want to switch to another compiler.

Comment: Ok, I will get that in mind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro `\texorpdfstring` can be used:

```
\section[\texorpdfstring{bla}{blablabla}]{blablabla}
```

An alternative is package [`hypbmsec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypbmsec).