# Changing concrete preamble from pdfLatex to Lua(la)tex

Tags: luatex, conversion, preamble

I got an example handout which was written for pdflatex but since I use lualatex i'm pretty sure that I have to make some changes to the preamble.

From there [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex) i already know that i have to change from

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and from

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
```

but as soon as kick out inputenc it removes "ä" and "ü" from

```
{\sstenbx Fakultät für } \\[-1mm]
```

in the final output. I assume it happens because

```
\font\ssten=cmss10
\font\sstenbx=cmssbx10
```

only works when inputenc is loaded with utf-8?
Everwhere else(besides that header part) there are no problems with those characters...

The other problem I am facing is that according to the link i have to replace `amssymb` with `unicode-math` but as soon as i do so the defined environments aren't found anymore... so i assume that any part of the definition of the theorems depends on amssymb...

My concrete question is now what exactly do i have to change when moving from `inputenc` to `fontspec`, from `babel` to `polyglossia` and from `amssymb` to `unicode-math` in order to achieve the same output?

theorems.sty

```
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}

\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}

\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremseparator{:}

\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}
\newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newframedtheorem{krl}{Korollar}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{bsp}{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bem}{Bemerkung}

\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{bew}{Beweis}
```

Handout.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% useful packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{theorems}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\voffset=-2cm
\hoffset=-0.75cm
\textheight=22cm
\textwidth=15cm
\footskip=1.5cm
% w/o page numbers
\pagestyle{empty}
% w/ page numbers
% \pagestyle{plain}
\unitlength1cm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% different font style for the upper box
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\font\ssten=cmss10
\font\sstenbx=cmssbx10
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

% page head with pic
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\parskip0pt
\parindent0pt
\hspace*{0.1cm}

\begin{picture}(4,2)
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pic}}
\end{picture}
\hspace{6cm}\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\vspace*{-16mm}
\begin{tabular}{l}
{\sstenbx Fakultät für } \\[-1mm]
{\sstenbx Institute of } \\
{\ssten Name} \\
{\ssten Date}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\normalsize
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Headings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vskip1cm
\begin{center}
{\bf\large Topic \\ 
\vskip0.4cm Lecture title}
\end{center}
\vskip0.4cm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% given environments, examples
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Normal text

\begin{defn}
definitions
\end{defn}

\begin{lemma}
lemmas
\end{lemma}

\begin{bsp}
examples
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\item 2nd
\end{itemize}
\end{bsp}

\begin{satz}
Sätze(theorem)
\end{satz}

\begin{bew}
proof
\end{bew}

\begin{krl}
corollary
\end{krl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, that document should get a few updates to be proper LaTeX2e, right now, there is a lot of 2.09 stuff going on that went obsolete 20 years ago.

Comment: well i'd be pretty happy to get someone to help me/explain me how to make it being an up-to-date tex-file. Currently i'm in the 2nd term/semester, studying mathematics but i only am able to write plain formulas o.O

Comment: Ditch the `\font` declarations. Then replace the occurences where you use them, e.g., write: `{\footnotesize\textsf{\textbf{Fakultät für}}}` or
`{\footnotesize\textsf{Name}}`

Comment: `ntheorem` uses `\Box` from `amssymb` for the end-of-proof marker.  `amsthm` makes no assumption that the `amsfonts` package is loaded, but draws an open box with rules.  might be worth mentioning that to the maintainer of `ntheorem`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi so i think i rather should've asked for what i "should" than what i "must" change :/ that it's not compilable wasn't my intension o.O well tbh it even compiled for me in lualatex :/

Comment: As a general piece of advice, I'd recommend against adopting a preamble from someone else if you don't understand what it is doing.

Comment: thanks to all for the support (upvotes) (either way, for giving me access to chat or just because you like the question ;) )

Answer (score 3):

There are things in your current document, that are valid in TeX or valid in LaTeX2.09, but obsolete in current LaTeX, LaTeX2e.

Following an example using current KOMA-script to set up the document. As this seems to be some kind of lecture notes, which are intended to have the same appearance, it is adviced to write a short wrapper class.

[image: rapusCurrentDocLuatex]

This is the header of the output, we can see that the author and the date would be printed twice. That can be dealt with in a wrapper class.

In the document that did not work with LuaLaTeX, old TeX-font commands have been used, whereas LuaTeX uses a completely different font handling system. 
The margins were set by hand. In the example below, (relatively narrow) margins are set using the capabilities of package `typearea`. If the need for specific margins exists, package `geometry` can be of help.

I left the theorem stuff mostly untouched, but changed the filename to the ending `tex` and used regular `input` to read the file.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-theorems.tex}
    \usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
    \usepackage{framed}

    \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}

    \theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
    \theoremseparator{:}

    \newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}
    \newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
    \newframedtheorem{krl}{Korollar}
    \newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{bsp}{Beispiel}
    \newtheorem{bem}{Bemerkung}

%   \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
    \newtheorem{bew}{Beweis}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,headlines=5,headinclude,DIV=18]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}%for this mwe
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\sffamily}
\ihead[{\includegraphics[height=4.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}]{}
\ohead*{Fakultät für Sonnenschein\\Institute of rainbows\\Name \\ Date}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\input{\jobname-theorems}


\title{This lectures topic}
\author{rapus}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Normal text \blindtext

\begin{defn}
    definitions
\end{defn}

\begin{lemma}
    lemmas
\end{lemma}

\begin{bsp}
    examples
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first
        \item 2nd
    \end{itemize}
\end{bsp}

\begin{satz}
    Sätze(theorem)
\end{satz}

\begin{bew}
    proof
\end{bew}

\begin{krl}
    corollary
\end{krl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any morequestions? Feel free to ask. As you are writing in german, you are very welcome to ask questions over at TeXwelt.de or golatex.de :-)

Comment: you used amsfonts where but anywhere else i read that fontspec is all you need instead so why you used it here, are there any advantages?

Comment: @rapus95 My bad, should be `amssymb` to make the `blacksquare` available. This on the other hand load `amsfonts`.

Comment: well since `amssymb` seems to be kind of deprecated with lua(la)tex (people said to use `unicode-math` instead) there can be any other symbol that looks similar :) (Contact info in my profile, prefer moving to IM, due to lang and better reaction times)

Comment: Yes, unicode math is definitely  preferred.

Comment: Everything said privately is lost for others looking for solutions. You will soon have enough reputation to koin us in chat on-site, we can also create our own chat room. You can also use github (for example) to get user input and improvement suggestions. The format of this site, Question-Answer, isn't well suited for discussion.

Comment: That's why i wanted to move :D because i assume that most of my questions are kind of trivial o.O but seem to be very complicated for me as beginner

Comment: We all started at some time and we all were confused first. I was forced to read `lshort` (`l2kurz`) and `l2tabu` and everything (naja, most of it) has been quite simple since. LaTeX for complete novices is also great, wish i had this in the beginning. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html

Comment: thanks so far for the link :) well now i gonna try to get that 20th repu point anyhow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23470/discussion-between-rapus95-and-johannes-b).