# Inputenc error with Swedish letter Å in .bib file

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings

I am writing a scientific document using natbib for the bibliography. The `.tex` file and .bib file are UTF-8 encoded and I have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble.

> One of my references has an author named "Åke" and I get the error
>   "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �. (U+31)
>   (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX."
>   caused by the letter Å. I can get rid of the error by e.g. manually replacing Å by \AA in the .bib file.

What I do not understand is the code point shown in the error message. Normally I would solve the problem by putting a `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{codepoint}{definition}` in the preamble of the document.

But the codepoint 31 belongs to the symbol 1 (and an error message tells me that I am not allowed to change its meaning via `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`). The actual codepoint of the letter `Å` is `00C5`, but when I try `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C5}{\AA}`, the error does not disappear.

Does anyone of you have a possible explanation of this behavior?

Comment: Is Åke a first name? Then bibtex is probably trying to create an initial and breaks the utf8 in parts.

Comment: `bibtex` works only by chance with non-ASCII encoding. You should consider moving to biber/biblatex... see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238725/utf8-and-bibtex-problems  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243836/bibliography-bib-encoding-utf8-french-accents and all the linked posts...

Comment: @daleif IIRC `bibtex8` is meant for 8bit encodings like ISO-8859-1 as oppsed to 7bit ASCII. UTF-8 is a different matter still.

Comment: @RalfStubner by bad then